# Cost of len() function

Tags: python, collections, time-complexity

What is the cost of [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function for Python built-ins? (list/tuple/string/dictionary)

Answer (score 501, accepted):

It's **O(1)** (constant time, not depending of actual length of the element - very fast) on every type you've mentioned, plus `set` and others such as `array.array`.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer!  Are there any native types for which this is not the case?

Comment: interesting that get length runtime is only mentioned for list here - https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity [not mentioned for other types]

Comment: But why is it `O(1)?`

Comment: len() is a very frequent operation, and making it O(1) is extremely easy from the viewpoint of implementation -- Python just keeps each collection's "number of items" (length) stored and updated as part of the collection data structure.

Comment: I assume its only O(1) because it was already calculated at time of creation and getting len(x) is just accessing that stored value

Answer (score 166):

Calling `len()` on those data types is **O(1)** in [CPython](http://www.python.org), the official and most common implementation of the Python language. Here's a link to a table that provides the algorithmic complexity of many different functions in CPython:

[TimeComplexity Python Wiki Page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Answer (score 124):

All those objects keep track of their own length. The time to extract the length is small (O(1) in big-O notation) and mostly consists of [rough description, written in Python terms, not C terms]: look up "len" in a dictionary and dispatch it to the built_in len function which will look up the object's `__len__` method and call that ... all it has to do is `return self.length`

Comment: why doesn't `length` show up in dictionary by `dir(list)` ?

Comment: @ViFI Because it is just a example. The illustrated `list.lenght` variable is implemented in C, not Python.

Comment: For any of the built-in types, `len(x)` doesn't need to perform a `dict` lookup on CPython; the length getting function is stored in a dedicated slot in the `PyTypeObject` struct, that can be looked up at a constant offset, so finding that function involves: 1) Extracting the type from the object (a lookup at offset in C), 2) Looking up `tp_len` in the type (another lookup at offset in C), 3) Calling said function (C function call through function pointer), which 4) Looks up the actual length from the original instance (a final lookup at offset in C), then 5) Converts to Python level `int`.

Comment: Point is, no `dict` involved (aside from the global ones to find the built-in `len` itself, and modern CPython uses caches so it doesn't even do that most of the time); all the offsets are baked into the compiled code, so no strings are involved, let alone hashing and bucket lookups. A `dict` lookup *is* involved if you get the length by calling `x.__len__()`, [which is why the `__len__` method is slower than the `len` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20302558/364696).

Answer (score 96):

The below measurements provide evidence that `len()` is O(1) for oft-used data structures.

A note regarding `timeit`: When the `-s` flag is used and two strings are passed to `timeit` the first string is executed only once and is not timed.

#### List:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "l = range(10);" "len(l)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0677 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "l = range(1000000);" "len(l)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0688 usec per loop
```

#### Tuple:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "t = (1,)*10;" "len(t)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0712 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "t = (1,)*1000000;" "len(t)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0699 usec per loop
```

#### String:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "s = '1'*10;" "len(s)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0713 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "s = '1'*1000000;" "len(s)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0686 usec per loop
```

#### Dictionary (dictionary-comprehension available in 2.7+):

```
$ python -mtimeit -s"d = {i:j for i,j in enumerate(range(10))};" "len(d)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0711 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s"d = {i:j for i,j in enumerate(range(1000000))};" "len(d)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0727 usec per loop
```

#### Array:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s"import array;a=array.array('i',range(10));" "len(a)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0682 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s"import array;a=array.array('i',range(1000000));" "len(a)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0753 usec per loop
```

#### Set (set-comprehension available in 2.7+):

```
$ python -mtimeit -s"s = {i for i in range(10)};" "len(s)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0754 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s"s = {i for i in range(1000000)};" "len(s)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0713 usec per loop
```

#### Deque:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s"from collections import deque;d=deque(range(10));" "len(d)"
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0163 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s"from collections import deque;d=deque(range(1000000));" "len(d)"
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0163 usec per loop
```

Comment: This is not so good of a benchmark even though it shows what we already know. This is because range(10) and range(1000000) is not supposed to be O(1).

Comment: This is by far the best answer. You should just add a conclusion just in case someone doesn't realize the constant time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added a note about the O(1) complexity of `len()`, and also fixed the measurements to properly use the `-s` flag.

Comment: It is important to note that saving the length into a variable could save a significant amount of computational time:
 `python -m timeit -s "l = range(10000);" "len(l); len(l); len(l)"`
223 nsec per loop
`python -m timeit -s "l = range(100);" "len(l)"`
66.2 nsec per loop

Answer (score 46):

**len is an O(1) because in your RAM, lists are stored as tables** (series of contiguous addresses). To know when the table stops the computer needs two things : length and start point. That is why len() is a O(1), the computer stores the value, so it just needs to look it up.

Comment: I don't think this is true for python lists. They're linked lists, not arrays, so contiguous addresses are not guaranteed

Comment: @bluppfisk You are totally wrong. Here are the python docs https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented-in-cpython

Answer (score 1):

It is `O(1)` in CPython because length is derived from the size attribute on the Pyobject representing the list. See [1], [2] and [3] in that order:

[1]:

```
static PyObject *
listiter_len(_PyListIterObject *it, PyObject *Py_UNUSED(ignored))
{
    Py_ssize_t len;
    if (it->it_seq) {
        len = PyList_GET_SIZE(it->it_seq) - it->it_index;
        if (len >= 0)
            return PyLong_FromSsize_t(len);
    }
    return PyLong_FromLong(0);
}
```

[2]:

```
static inline Py_ssize_t PyList_GET_SIZE(PyObject *op) {
    PyListObject *list = _PyList_CAST(op);
    return Py_SIZE(list);
}
```

[3]

```
static inline Py_ssize_t Py_SIZE(PyObject *ob) {
    assert(ob->ob_type != &PyLong_Type);
    assert(ob->ob_type != &PyBool_Type);
    PyVarObject *var_ob = _PyVarObject_CAST(ob);
    return var_ob->ob_size;
}
```

[1] [listiter_len](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d6892c2b9263b39ea1c7905667942914b6a24b2c/Objects/listobject.c#L3263)

[2] [PyList_GET_SIZE](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d6892c2b9263b39ea1c7905667942914b6a24b2c/Include/cpython/listobject.h#L32)

[3] [Py_SIZE](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d6892c2b9263b39ea1c7905667942914b6a24b2c/Include/object.h#L211)