# Python : How `len()` is executed

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cost of len() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function)

How Python calculates length of a list(using `len()` function )?Does it go through a `for` or `while` *loop* to do the same or it has some internal variable that stores the length of the list ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function

Comment: “How is `x` implemented” and “What's the cost of `x`” are two different questions with different answers.

Comment: @Petr: Except that the cost of `x` offers a pretty big clue as to how `x` is implemented.  If `len` runs in O(1), for example, you can be pretty sure that there's an internal variable; O(N) probably means it counts them individually; and higher means the Python devs were idiots.  :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, CPython lists have an internal variable for the length.

It's called [`ob_size`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/edf944ab87c5/Include/listobject.h#l22); all [variable-sized objects](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/edf944ab87c5/Include/object.h#l110) have it.

Answer (score 5):

It uses an internal variable that stores the length of the list (as do all other variable-length object types in Python). So len() is an O(1) operation regardless of the size of the list (i.e. it runs in constant time).

Here's the [implementation of len() for lists](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e7b6dca28a2f/Objects/listobject.c#l431), here's the [Py_SIZE macro](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e7b6dca28a2f/Include/object.h#l116) it calls, and here's the [declaration of ob_size](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e7b6dca28a2f/Include/object.h#l90) that Py_SIZE uses.

Answer (score 4):

```
a = range(10)
b = range(1000000)

timeit len(a) # 85.4 ns
timeit len(b) # 94.4 ns
```

It doesn't look like a loop.

Answer (score 3):

From python's view, the `len()` function calls the class's `__len__()` method, which returns the internally known length.