# What is the big-o notation for the `len()` function in Python?

Tags: python, big-o

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cost of len() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function)

Does `len()` iterate over the objects in a list and then return their count? Thus giving it a **O(n)**.

Or....

Does a python list keep a count of any objects that are appended to it and removed from it and then simply return this "count" when `len()` is called?  Thus giving it **O(1)**.

Comment: it's `O(1)` this is what you need : http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A Python list knows its own length; `len` takes [O(1) time](http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented). [Lists are actually arrays](http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented), not linked lists as in Lisp, where `length` takes linear time.

Comment: "proof"  http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 11):

For all built-in objects that define `__len__()`, it will be O(1).  If you implement `__len__()` for your own objects, it might be anything.