# How to assert two list contain the same elements in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

When writing test cases, I often need to assert that two list contain the same elements without regard to their order.

I have been doing this by converting the lists to sets.

Is there any simpler way to do this?

**EDIT**:

As @MarkDickinson pointed out, I can just use [TestCase.assertItemsEqual](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertItemsEqual).

Notes that `TestCase.assertItemsEqual` is new in Python2.7.
If you are using an older version of Python, you can use [unittest2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2) - a backport of new features of Python 2.7.

Comment: Simpler than `set(x) == set(y)`?  How much simpler can you get?

Comment: @cdhowie: This will fail when there are redundant elements in the lists.

Comment: @cdhowie What about extending `TestCase` and add a `assertSetEqual`? IMHO, calling `self.assertSetEqual` is simpler than remembering to use `set(x) == set(y)` anywhere.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget It's not clear from the original question whether that should be a failure case or not.

Comment: If you're unit testing, what's wrong with `TestCase.assertItemsEqual`?

Comment: @MarkDickinson "without regard to their order".

Comment: @MarkDickinson I didn't know that before. It's really nice to have, but I'm using Python2.6 and `assertItemsEqual` is new in version2.7.

Comment: Ah yes, Python 2.6 would be an excellent reason *not* to use `assertItemsEqual`. :-)

Comment: @MarkDickinson You should make that an answer so OP can accept it and we can upvote it - that really is the best answer considering the question states "writing test cases". This is a top 2 result when Googling "assert lists equal python".

Comment: [assertSetEqual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertSetEqual) is available for python 3.1. referring to @satoru comment

Answer (score 271, accepted):

As of Python 3.2 `unittest.TestCase.assertItemsEqual`([doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertItemsEqual)) has been replaced by `unittest.TestCase.assertCountEqual`([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertCountEqual)) which does exactly what you are looking for, as you can read from the python [standard library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/unittest.html). The method is somewhat misleadingly named but it does exactly what you are looking for.

> a and b have the same elements in the same number, regardless of their order

Here a simple example which compares two lists having the same elements but in a different order.

- using `assertCountEqual` the test will succeed
- using `assertListEqual` the test will fail due to the order difference of the two lists

Here a little example script.

```
import unittest


class TestListElements(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.expected = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
        self.result = ['baz', 'foo', 'bar']

    def test_count_eq(self):
        """Will succeed"""
        self.assertCountEqual(self.result, self.expected)

    def test_list_eq(self):
        """Will fail"""
        self.assertListEqual(self.result, self.expected)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

**Side Note :** Please make sure that the elements in the lists you are comparing are sortable.

Comment: Thanks. The original name was so much clearer, I had seen that method, but assumed it checked the count.

Comment: Is there a way to compare to lists that are "almost equal"? In the sense that given an error, i want to assert the equal if the  difference btw the elements in the lists are within the error?

Comment: Thanks. But *downright* misleading, I would have called it!

Comment: This is not correct - try self.assertCountEqual({1: [1, 2, 3]}, {1: [5, 6, 7]})

Comment: Note - in Python 2 you can use the six library to do six.assertCountEqual, for any future py3 upgrade :)

Comment: Is there a way to see if everything in list B is in list A. But not everything in list A has to be in list B. When list B is bigger than list A and may have (more than likely) duplicates in it. So I have some predictions and I want to make sure that every prediction belongs to list A

Comment: Is there a way to check the opposite, that is, whether to lists are NOT equal?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the way `assertCountEqual` is implemented it will always generate a `fail()` if something is different. I couldn't find a way to inverse the behavior.

Answer (score 63):

Slightly faster version of the implementation (If you know that most couples lists will have different lengths):

```
def checkEqual(L1, L2):
    return len(L1) == len(L2) and sorted(L1) == sorted(L2)
```

Comparing:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: sorting([1,2,3], [3,2,1]))
2.42745304107666
>>> timeit(lambda: lensorting([1,2,3], [3,2,1]))
2.5644469261169434 # speed down not much (for large lists the difference tends to 0)

>>> timeit(lambda: sorting([1,2,3], [3,2,1,0]))
2.4570400714874268
>>> timeit(lambda: lensorting([1,2,3], [3,2,1,0]))
0.9596951007843018 # speed up
```

Comment: Your speedup comes from (1) no branching (valid), (2) a `len` check before sorting. The `len` check is O(n) and only helps in cases when it returns `False`. Else, it hurts the actual runtime (not complexity) by adding two linear passes (one on each of `L1` and `L2`). Thus while the runtime complexity is still O(nlogn) (from sorting), the O(n) will hurt the number of seconds it takes for this function to `return`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, add comparison (without branching difference)

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. Yours is actually a better solution if OP knows a priori that most of the pairs of lists that he compares will be of unequal length

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: `len()` has O(1) complexity (constant time). There is no pass to get the value.

Comment: @pepr: [you're right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function)! I was not aware of that. Thank you for clarifying

Comment: This doesn’t work if your list contains unorderable types like `dict`.

Comment: the marked duplicated post wasn't asking for unit testing and further more that question wasn't stated clear enough. so I don't think this question should be marked as duplicate as the other one.

Comment: This is not correct! Try self.assertCountEqual({1: [1, 2, 3]}, {1: [5, 6, 7]})

Comment: @variable None of the functions in this thread are intended to be called with dicts. The question asks "How to assert two **list** contain the same elements in Python?" (emphasis mine). Recursively checking list order in a nested structure is a completely separate issue.

Comment: Sorting is slow O(n log(n)), so this answer is misleading. If performance matters, use a lookup table (dictionary or `Collections.counter`) O(n). That said, in most cases you wouldn't want to use large lists in tests anyway so it probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 41):

Given

```py
l1 = [a,b]
l2 = [b,a]
```

[In Python *>= 3.0*](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html?highlight=assertcountequal#unittest.TestCase.assertCountEqual)

```py
assertCountEqual(l1, l2) # True
```

[In Python *>= 2.7*](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html?highlight=assertequal#unittest.TestCase.assertItemsEqual), the above function was named:

```py
assertItemsEqual(l1, l2) # True
```

[In Python *< 2.7*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2)

```py
import unittest2
assertItemsEqual(l1, l2) # True
```

[Via `six` module](https://six.readthedocs.io/#six.assertCountEqual) (Any Python version)

```py
import unittest
import six
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        six.assertCountEqual(self, self.l1, self.l2) # True
```

Comment: **If there are only unique values in list**
Converting them to set using set(l1)& set(2) & asserting using assertSetEqual(l1, l2) also helps.

Comment: +1 for your solution @Abhijeet as it actually checks if the contents of the list matches, which is useful for comparing a set of unique ids.

Comment: Try self.assertCountEqual({1: [1, 2, 3]}, {1: [5, 6, 7]})

Answer (score 20):

Converting your lists to sets will tell you that they contain the same elements. But this method cannot confirm that they contain the same number of all elements. For example, your method will fail in this case:

```
L1 = [1,2,2,3]
L2 = [1,2,3,3]
```

You are likely better off sorting the two lists and comparing them:

```
def checkEqual(L1, L2):
    if sorted(L1) == sorted(L2):
        print "the two lists are the same"
        return True
    else:
        print "the two lists are not the same"
        return False
```

Note that this does not alter the structure/contents of the two lists. Rather, the sorting creates two new lists

Comment: What is a proper name for this if I'm going to encapsulate it in a function?

Comment: "abstract/encapsulate into a function". Answer edited to abstract my code into a function

Comment: In my shop we use 'assertElementsEqual', makes sense to us.

Comment: This will fail if the lists contain 'unhashable elements' (for example dictionaries) - whatever that means: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Answer (score 1):

Needs **ensure** library but you can compare list by:

> ensure([1, 2]).contains_only([2, 1])

This will not raise assert exception. Documentation of thin is really thin so i would recommend to look at [ensure's codes on github](https://github.com/kislyuk/ensure/blob/master/ensure/__init__.py)