# Iterating over a 2 dimensional python list

Tags: python, loops, multidimensional-array

I have created a 2 dimension array like:

```
rows =3
columns= 2
mylist = [[0 for x in range(columns)] for x in range(rows)]
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        mylist[i][j] = '%s,%s'%(i,j)
print mylist
```

Printing this list gives an output:

```
[  ['0,0', '0,1'], ['1,0', '1,1'], ['2,0', '2,1']   ]
```

where each list item is a string of the format 'row,column'

Now given this list, i want to iterate through it in the order:

```
'0,0'
'1,0'
'2,0'
'0,1'
'1,1'
'2,1'
```

that is iterate through 1st column then 2nd column and so on. How do i do it with a loop ?

This Question pertains to pure python list while the question which is marked as same pertains to numpy arrays. They are clearly different

Comment: @NominSim that refers to a numpy array, which doesn't necessarily translate to his problem

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `zip` and `itertools.chain`. Something like:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l = chain.from_iterable(zip(*l))
<itertools.chain object at 0x104612610>
>>> list(l)
['0,0', '1,0', '2,0', '0,1', '1,1', '2,1']
```

Comment: @AndyHayden Actually, it's ok for active interactive shell user. Updated answer with direct variable name.

Comment: name 'l' is not defined

Comment: @Sérgio l is a list...

Answer (score 140):

same way you did the fill in, but reverse the indexes:

```
>>> for j in range(columns):
...     for i in range(rows):
...        print mylist[i][j],
... 
0,0 1,0 2,0 0,1 1,1 2,1
>>>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it is simple and easy to understand. One may not be familiar with the clever functions used in the other answers, but with only a quick look at the code, it's obvious how this solution works.  Because of that, this answer is the most Pythonic.

Comment: Hmm.. What if each of the children lists doesn't have the save length (rows here) ?

Comment: @sonlexqt iterate indexes of the longest row and use `try ... except IndexError` around the print operand. (On my cell so can't provide exact example)

Comment: But this doesn't work if the number of rows is more than the number of columns.

Answer (score 104):

This is the correct way.

```
>>> x = [ ['0,0', '0,1'], ['1,0', '1,1'], ['2,0', '2,1'] ]
>>> for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(x[i])):
                print(x[i][j])


0,0
0,1
1,0
1,1
2,0
2,1
>>>
```

Comment: This isn't very pythonic.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> mylist = [["%s,%s"%(i,j) for j in range(columns)] for i in range(rows)]
>>> mylist
[['0,0', '0,1', '0,2'], ['1,0', '1,1', '1,2'], ['2,0', '2,1', '2,2']]
>>> zip(*mylist)
[('0,0', '1,0', '2,0'), ('0,1', '1,1', '2,1'), ('0,2', '1,2', '2,2')]
>>> sum(zip(*mylist),())
('0,0', '1,0', '2,0', '0,1', '1,1', '2,1', '0,2', '1,2', '2,2')
```

Answer (score 4):

`zip` will transpose the list, after that you can concatenate the outputs.

```
In [3]: zip(*[ ['0,0', '0,1'], ['1,0', '1,1'], ['2,0', '2,1'] ])
Out[3]: [('0,0', '1,0', '2,0'), ('0,1', '1,1', '2,1')]
```

Comment: But @Alexey's answer is better.

Comment: Why is Alexey's answer better? This uses built-in functions only, and doesn't seem substantially more resource intensive.

Comment: @Z4-tier This response returns a list with 2 tuples. Alexey's answer returns a single list with all values

Answer (score 3):

Ref: [zip built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

`zip()` in conjunction with the `*` operator can be used to `unzip` a list

```
unzip_lst = zip(*mylist)
for i in unzip_lst:
    for j in i:
        print j
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [el[0] if i < len(mylist) else el[1] for i,el in enumerate(mylist + mylist)]
['0,0', '1,0', '2,0', '0,1', '1,1', '2,1']
```

Comment: I like zip method better, but I thought I would throw out a wacky alternative.

Comment: does this evaluate `len(myList)` only once, or does it recalculate it every iteration?

Comment: @Z4-tier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function