# How to run loop through table with diff rows ? for example this is input ([[0,4],[2,4],[-1,3]] and output i want is this [[0,1.5],[2,1.5],[1.5,3]]

Tags: python, list, for-loop, rows

// It is just changing values of first row and not the whole table ? can someone tell me how  to run loop in whole table

```
def remove_outliers(table):
     mx = max(map(max, table))
     mn = min(map(min, table))
     avg = (mx + mn) / 2
     for row in table:
         row[:] = [avg if x in (mx, mn) else x for x in row]
         return table
```

Comment: Is it answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548668/iterating-over-a-2-dimensional-python-list?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `return table` is intended wrong. It will return after the first row is processed. Try this:

```py
def remove_outliers(table):
    mx = max(map(max, table))
    mn = min(map(min, table))
    avg = (mx + mn) / 2
    for row in table:
        row[:] = [avg if x in (mx, mn) else x for x in row]
    return table
```

Answer (score 0):

The return statement is in the wrong place. The function will exit in the first iteration itself.
Un-indent return statement out of for loop.
Then it will exit after the complete iteration

```
for row in table:
    row[:] = [avg if x in (mx, mn) else x for x in row]
return table
```

Comment: yup it works . My IDE was showing return statement at that place only

Comment: Awesome. But why are returning the table again instead of avg or something??