# How can I delete element in log(n) from priority queue implemented through heapq in python?

Tags: python, heap

I have implemented priority queue from heapq data structure in python. Now I want to delete a particular element (by value) from the heap maintaining the heap invariant.
I know it can be done by removing the element and heapify() again but that is O(n), and might be very slow since I have a very large heap.

The other thing that I am trying is, if I had known index I could have replaced it with last element and done _shiftup().
But since I don't know the index, I'll have to search, which again is linear time.

Can I keep a parallel dict to point to location and use it? How can I update such dict with every insert to queue?

EDIT:

Actually I need above to implement decreaseKey() in O(log n) time. If there's a better method to directly do that, that's also equivalently good.

Answer (score 3):

You may have read this already, but you could use the approach the [the `heapq` docs suggest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes), which is to just mark the element as removed, without actually removing it from the heap:

> The remaining challenges revolve around finding a pending task and
>   making changes to its priority or removing it entirely. Finding a task
>   can be done with a dictionary pointing to an entry in the queue.
>
> Removing the entry or changing its priority is more difficult because
>   it would break the heap structure invariants. So, a possible solution
>   is to mark the existing entry as removed and add a new entry with the
>   revised priority:
>
> ```py
> pq = []                         # list of entries arranged in a heap
> entry_finder = {}               # mapping of tasks to entries
> REMOVED = '<removed-task>'      # placeholder for a removed task
> counter = itertools.count()     # unique sequence count
>
> def add_task(task, priority=0):
>     'Add a new task or update the priority of an existing task'
>     if task in entry_finder:
>         remove_task(task)
>     count = next(counter)
>     entry = [priority, count, task]
>     entry_finder[task] = entry
>     heappush(pq, entry)
>
> def remove_task(task):
>     'Mark an existing task as REMOVED.  Raise KeyError if not found.'
>     entry = entry_finder.pop(task)
>     entry[-1] = REMOVED
>
> def pop_task():
>     'Remove and return the lowest priority task. Raise KeyError if empty.'
>     while pq:
>         priority, count, task = heappop(pq)
>         if task is not REMOVED:
>             del entry_finder[task]
>             return task
>     raise KeyError('pop from an empty priority queue')
> ```

This way the removal is just a `O(1)` lookup in a dict. And the removed item will just be ignored when it's popped from the queue later (at a cost of an extra `O(log n)` on the `pop_task` operation). The drawback of course, is that if a client is not actually popping items from the queue, the size of the heap will grow, even though it  items are being "removed" according to the API.

Comment: Removal might be `O(1)` when you call it, but it requires `O(log n)` time in total.

Comment: @dano Yes actually I had seen this approach, but I thought whether there is a better solution also. Also with this approach isEmpty() function will not remain O(1), right? Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: @Veedrac Yes, thanks. I've made that more clear in my answer.

Comment: @Naman I wouldn't worry about `isEmpty` being more expensive because the only costs you pay are costs you would have payed if you didn't do the removal lazily.

Comment: @Naman The `entry_finder` dict should reflect the true length of the queue, since items are popped from it when `remove_task` is called. ([`len(dict_object)` is `O(1)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function))

Comment: @dano Actually I have one more doubt, I want to use this in decreaseKey() operation that I am trying to write in O(log n). The problem with soft delete will be, it will bloat up the size of heap as many times I call decreaseKey. Is there any other solution also for this?

Comment: @Naman I mentioned this drawback in my original answer, too. The "mark as removed" approach sacrifices memory usage to make removal/priority changes `O(log n)`. If memory usage is a concern, and you're frequently changing priority of keys in the queue, without popping items as well, you may want to consider another approach.

Comment: @dano Actually my end goal is pretty simple and standard. I am implementing Prim's algorithm for MST on a graph that have around 2 million of edges. Now The only way I can implement Prim's in Elog(V) is when I can perform E decreaseKey operations in log(V) times. Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: @Naman You can still do `decreaseKey` in `log(V)` time using this implementation, you just end up using `E` extra memory to do it. There's a description of a Python Prim's algorithm implementation [here](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Graphs/PrimsSpanningTreeAlgorithm.html?highlight=decreasekey) that claims to have a `Elog(V)` `decreaseKey` implementation, but when I look at [the code](https://github.com/bnmnetp/pythonds/blob/master/graphs/priorityQueue.py#L73), the implementation looks like it does a `O(N)` lookup of the item to change the priority of.

Comment: @dano It does look like it is O(n), since it is doing linear search. So what would you recommend in this situation? Should I implement my own binary heap in python and when I am inserting I can keep track of each element's location? I thought it to be a pretty standard problem. I am a bit shocked as this cannot be done with python heapq.

Comment: @Naman I think that's probably your best option. It looks like you could implement this with fairly minimal changes to `heapq` - of course the problem there is you're stuck with a pure Python implementation, rather than the faster, C-implementation provided by the `_heapq` module. The changes are probably pretty similar for `_heapq`, though, if you're comfortable writing C.

Comment: @dano I think I am fairly comfortable with C but not sure whether I can do that here, since it's a part of assignment and I am mostly not supposed to do changes in python's own module. Probably I'll build a all python heap and use it. Hope when I am done, i'll put it somewhere to use for everyone. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @dano: In `pop_task()` method the `if` condition will be always true because you are changing `REMOVED` in dict not in the heap. I think you are not deleting anything.

Comment: @IsanSahoo All the code in my answer comes [directly from the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes).