# Does the len() built-in function iterates through the collection to calculate its length, or does it access a collection's attribute?

Tags: python, python-internals

Python has many [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html), and `len()` is one of them.

> Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may be a sequence (such as a string, bytes, tuple, list, or range) or a collection (such as a dictionary, set, or frozen set).

If collections and sequences are objects, they could hold a `length` attribute that can be updated every time something changes. Accessing this attribute would be a fast way to retrieve the collection's length.

Another approach is to iterate through the collection and count the number of items on the fly.

How does `len()` calculates said length? Through iteration or attribute access? One, none, both, other approaches?

Comment: See [Cost of len() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Python built-in collections cache the length in an attribute. Using `len()` will not iterate over all elements to count them, no.

Keeping the length as an attribute is cheap and easy to maintain. Given that the Python built-in collection types are used so widely, it'd be unwise for them *not* to do this.

Python built-in types with a length are typically built on top of the [`PyObject_VAR_HEAD` struct](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject_VAR_HEAD), which includes an `ob_size` entry. The [`Py_SIZE` macro](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b61578bb5014/Include/object.h#l116) can then be used to implement the [`object.__len__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) (e.g. the [`PySequenceMethods.sq_length` slot in the C-API](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PySequenceMethods.sq_length)). See the [`listobject.c` implementation for `list_length`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b61578bb5014/Objects/listobject.c#l431) for example.

Comment: Sometimes even, the length of a collection is not the same as the length of its iterator. E.g. a pandas DataFrame returns as length the number of rows, while its iterator iterates over the columns!

Comment: @kadee: so? You can also iterate over the rows in Pandas, and several other iterations to boot. What has that got to do with specifying a length?

Comment: @kadee (and if you need to know the number of columns, use `len(dataframe.columns)`).

Comment: It means that 'iterating through the collection and counting the number of items' as proposed by @Jamm would yield a different result than given by len(). In other words `len(dataframe) != len(list(dataframe.__iter__()))` I just found that remarkable.