# How to impment Hashmap like data structures in Python

Tags: python, string, hashmap

I'm kind of new to python and need some help. I was planning on having some sort of a hashMap-kind-of data structure to map a string to its length. How do I do this in python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries. There's not much point here, though, as `len(s)` is `O(1)` - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1115313/3001761

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add to a dictionary in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-to-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: Important question is to ask why you want to do this, you might be running into a classic XY problem here... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 3):

Use an empty dictionary, like so:

```
string_lengths = {}

string = 'hello'

string_lengths[string] = len(string)

print string_lengths
```

Output:

```
{'hello': 5}
```

Or do this for a list of strings:

```
string_lengths = {}

strings = ['Hello', 'There', 'Human Being']

for x in strings:
    string_lengths[x] = len(x)

print string_lengths
```

Output:

```
{'Human Being': 11, 'There': 5, 'Hello': 5}
```

Note that Dictionaries are unordered lists of key, value pairs.

To Reference the items in a dictionary:

`string_lengths['Hello']` returns `5`