# Filtering of two object list by tuple attributes

Tags: python

I have two list objects and I want only those elements in list1 with attribute tuples that match a tuple attribute in list2:

```
list1= [ojec1, objec2, objec3,....]

list2=[fig1,fig2,fig3,...]

for i in range (len(list1)):
  for j in range (len(list2)):
    if (list1[i].attr1==list2[j].attr1 & list1[i].attr2==list2[j].attr2):
      ...
```

is there a faster way??

Answer (score 3):

Your original code takes `O(N**2)` steps ([quadratic time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)) to find the matching elements due to the nested `for` loops.

It also uses `range(len(...))` and numeric indices, which can be cleaned up by just iterating over the elements! (see the [first example here](http://lignos.org/py_antipatterns/) for an explanation)

Also, for "logical and" you need to use the `and` operator, not `&` (as Kasra said it is for "bitwise AND").

So, to make this cleaner and more efficient (`O(N)`, linear time), I would do the following:

- loop over the two lists
- make a tuple of the attributes you care to match on
- use a dictionary to keep track of all the objects with matching tuples

Here is the code:

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Something(%s, %s)" % (self.a, self.b)

l1 = [Something(1,1), Something(1,2), Something(1,3)]
l2 = [Something(1,2), Something(2,2), Something(3,2)]

matches = {}
for obj in l1 + l2:
    k = (obj.a, obj.b)
    if k not in matches:
        matches[k] = []
    matches[k].append(obj)

for m in matches:
    if len(matches[m]) > 1:
        print "Match:", matches[m]
```

Output:

```
Match: [Something(1, 2), Something(1, 2)]
```

Comment: As I said already here you have `for obj in l1 + l2` which is O(2N) and and `for m in matches` which is O(X) and `len(matches[m])` within preceding loop that makes it O(X**2) also you have another extra blocks and its not pythonic at all.

Comment: `O(2N)` + `O(X)` is still `O(N)`. `len` is `O(1)` ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1115329)), so the loop is not `O(X**2)`. The overall complexity of this solution is `O(N)`. As for being pythonic, I agree your solution is more elegant, but at the cost of efficiency. I would definitely make the "less pythonic code" tradeoff for changing an `O(N**2)` algorithm to `O(N)`.

Comment: Just move this code into a helper function to keep the ugliness somewhere contained :)

Comment: Yep O(2N) + O(X) is still O(N), and the `len` in python is O(1) but by `len(matches[m])` I meant the indexing takes O(x) :-D . anyway it was a good suggestion ;)

Comment: I have the problem that the Attribute names differ from the the Objectlists: tuple1 = (obj.face,obj.label) and tuple2 = (obj.face,obj.elementLabel). Is there still a way?

Answer (score 2):

First of all `&` is bit-wise and for a logical and you need to use `and`.Then you don't need to use `len` and and extra indexing in a for loop to loop over the items of an iterable you can simply do:

```
for i in list1:
  for j in list2:
```

But here as a more efficient way you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get all pairs between your list items and check the condition.

```
from itertools import product

for i,j in product(list1,list2):
    if (i.attr1==j.attr1 and i.attr2==j.attr2):
```

Comment: Using itertools.product will take O(N**2) steps like the original code. See my answer for a linear solution.

Comment: @StevenKryskalla The original code is not  O(N\**2) at all, but `product` is O(N\**2) and is more efficient in terms of memory use, also you can not get the product between 2 list faster than this.  and in your code you have `for obj in l1 + l2:` which is O(2N) and and `for m in matches` which is O(X) and `len(matches[m])` within preceding loop that makes it O(X\**2) also you have another extra blocks and its not pythonic at all.

Answer (score 1):

If list 2 and list 1 both have size n, then this would take O(n) on average and O(n^2) worst case.

```
from collections import namedtuple


def main():
    # Item can be any class of your choice.
    # For simplcity I just used a named tuple.
    Item = namedtuple("item", ["a", "b"])

    l1 = [Item(1,1), Item(1,2), Item(1,2), Item(2, 2), Item(1,3)]
    l2 = [Item(1,2), Item(2,2), Item(3,2)]

    # O(n) time on average and O(n^2) worst case to create a set
    attributes_of_l2 = {(item.a, item.b) for item in l2}

    # Checking match is O(1) (average case, O(n) worst case)
    # Therefore, this takes O(n) time on average and O(n^2) worst case.
    items_to_keep = [item for item in l1 if (item.a, item.b) in attributes_of_l2]

    print(items_to_keep)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

`[item(a=1, b=2), item(a=1, b=2), item(a=2, b=2)]`

See https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity for time complexity of checking if an item is in a set.

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve the runtime is by optimizing match ops of attributes.

Iterate list1 and store its attribute in a hash as a key. Iterate list2 and lookup the attribute key in the earlier hash and do your thing.

Comment: Time complexity is O(m+n). Time to add List1 attributes in hash + Time to iterate List2 and lookup its element attributes in hash.