# performance of get the length of a string in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

When calling `len("1234567890")`, the performance is constant i.e. O(1), or linear to the length of the string, i.e. O(n) according to the length of the string (in this example, the length of the string is n=10)? If constant performance, why? And if linear performance, any ideas how to improve performance of getting the length of a string? Thanks.

Using Python 2.7.

regards,
Lin

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: It is O(1) as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function Why? I'll leave that for someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check it:

```
C:\>py -m timeit -s "x='a'*1000" "len(x)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0959 usec per loop

C:\>py -m timeit -s "x='a'*10000" "len(x)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0902 usec per loop

C:\>py -m timeit -s "x='a'*100000" "len(x)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0927 usec per loop
```

It's O(1).  The size of the string is stored in the object when it is created.

Comment: This reminds me of assembly where you had to store the length of strings for uses such as printing to stdout.

Comment: @MoonCheesez, it's all convention.  I could write assembly that uses nul-terminated strings instead, but it would be O(n) instead for getting length.

Comment: Thanks Mark, excellent reply, vote up and mark your reply as answer.