# Is there a better way to write the len of string to var while comparing to string lengths in python3

Tags: python, string

I am trying to get my head around single line evaluations and this is what I came up with. I am sure there is a better more pythonic what to write this line.

```
s1 = 'abcdef'
s2 = 'abcdefghi'

ln = len(s1) if len(s2) > len(s1) else len(s2)

print(ln)  # prints 6
```

edit: updated code
This is more understandable for me though the result is the same.

```
ln = len(s1) if len(s1) < len(s2) else len(s2)
```

This is much easier to read.

```
ln = min( len(s1), len(s2) )
```

Comment: This is perfectly Pythonic. The most improvement is simply to replace `ln` with the evaluation you have.

Comment: That's fine to be honest, trying to find the shortest way to do something isn't always the best thing to do; making sure it's readable and understandable is more important

Comment: `ln= min(len(s1), len(s2))`?

Comment: I changed the order of the inner s1 and s2 which makes it more readable `ln = len(s1) if len(s1) < len(s2) else len(s2)`. But I am going to go with @Rawing code.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the results of `len` in variables:

```
s1 = 'abcdef'
s2 = 'abcdefghi'
l1 = len(s1)
l2 = len(s2)

ln = l1 if l2 > l1 else l2
```

If you need to do this for more strings, you can use `min`. Doing this for just 2 strings is overkill though, and I don't recommend it:

```
ln = min(len(s) for s in (s1, s2, s3, ...))
```

Comment: You should store those values, because if you don't, python will evaluate this length each time it is asked for it. For long strings or more complicated functions, computations might be costly and slow down the program

Comment: @Fulaphex why write more code right now, just to hedge against an imaginary future where hypothetical costly computations, if put in a loop that doesn't yet exist, might slow it down enough to be a problem? Cross that bridge when you get to it.

Comment: It was a suggestion for future needs and a word of comment, on why in the answer this solution was used, what benefits are in such a way.

Comment: Writing `ln = min(map(len, (s1, s2)))` does not seem too difficult to read.

Comment: @Fulaphex, Python doesn't calculate the length each time you request it. [Build-in Iterables handle it in an appropiate way.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function)