# Is O(1) complexity of len(...) guaranteed by some PEP for built-in sequence types?

Tags: python

Many questions about cost of `len(...)` are answered but I haven't found any link to Python documentation.

Is it by standard (documented in some PEP) or just way how it's currently implemented in most Python implementations?

Comment: Clearly `O(1)` for lists: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: There's a thread with something similar here, but Alex Martelli did not provide any doc refs: [Cost of len() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye This question raised exactly after I read question you mention. Thanks for link, it really answers at least part of question.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation about time complexity for certain built-in python objects is [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

The `len()` function in python just calls the `__len__` method in your class. So if you built a custom class

```
class SlowLenList(object):

  def __init__(self, mylist):
    self.mylist = mylist

  def __len__(self):
    total = 1
    for item in self.mylist:
      total += 1
    return total
```

Then the complexity would be O(n) in this case. So it really depends on the object you are calling. I assume the built-in list and other objects are O(1) because they have an attribute on an instance that increments every time an item is added to the object.

Comment: Indeed, there are no guarantees on constant time `len` for custom classes. This answer should be here for the sake of completeness. But question is specifically about built-ins.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeSovetov I just wanted to give a brief explanation of how len() works so readers don't assume len() _always_ has the same time complexity (like it has some magic super efficient algorithm that works in all cases).

Comment: That's fine. As I said, this answer should be here.