# python playlist solution, how to finish is_repeating_playlist function?

Tags: python, algorithm

```
class Song:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.next = None

    def next_song(self, song):
        self.next = song 

    def is_repeating_playlist(self):
        """
        :returns: (bool) True if the playlist is repeating, False if not.
        """
        return None

first = Song("Hello")
second = Song("Eye of the tiger")

first.next_song(second);
second.next_song(first);
```

Comment: This is just a lot of code, what is your question?

Comment: the question is in the topic, duh!

Answer (score 8):

```
class Song:
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.next = None

def next_song(self, song):
    self.next = song 

def is_repeating_playlist(self):
    """
    :returns: (bool) True if the playlist is repeating, False if not.
    """
    songs = set()
    next_song = self
    while next_song:
        if next_song.name in songs:
            return True
        else:
            songs.add(next_song.name)
            next_song = next_song.next or None

    return False

first = Song("Anam Nesis - Contemplare")
second = Song("Petre Inspirescu - Anima")
third = Song("VOLK - Cântul Ielelor")

first.next_song(second);
second.next_song(third);


print(first.is_repeating_playlist())
```

Please make sure you use **set()** for increased speed.

The function "is_repeating_playlist" works in two steps:

- Iterates thru the (next) songs
- If it finds the next song in the already added songs list, then the list is repeating

Answer (score 2):

This is a linked list which is a very thoroughly examined data structure in computer science. You want to detect if your linked list has a loop.

Here is an answer adapted from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-loop-in-a-linked-list/

Because I heavily used that site (and because I wrote the function), you shouldn't hand this in as yours if it is homework. Instead, find [more info](https://medium.com/basecs/whats-a-linked-list-anyway-part-1-d8b7e6508b9d) on linked list and create your own solution.

```
class Song:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.next = None

    def next_song(self, song):
        self.next = song
```

Because I didn't use `self`, I made this a `staticmethod`.

```
    @staticmethod
    def is_repeating_playlist(first_song): 
        """
        :returns: (bool) True if the playlist is repeating, False if not.
        """
        songs_in_playlist = set()
        current_song = first_song
        while(current_song):
            if current_song.name in songs_in_playlist: # if we already saw this song
                return True
            songs_in_playlist.add(current_song.name)
            current_song = current_song.next
        return False # no repeats found
```

Now let's try it out:

```
first = Song("Hello")
second = Song("Eye of the tiger")

first.next_song(second);
second.next_song(first);

print(Song.is_repeating_playlist(first))
```

> True

And let's check one that doesn't repeat

```
first = Song("Hello")
second = Song("Eye of the tiger")
third = Song("We Will Rock You")
first.next_song(second);
second.next_song(third);

print(Song.is_repeating_playlist(first))
```

> False

Answer (score 2):

I'm just a newbie.. but check this out. It seems like to work well though.

```
def is_repeating_playlist(self):
    n = self
    x = set()
    while n is not None:
        x.add(n)
        n = n.next
        if n in x:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my solution is a little more performant than the answers already posted. I don't use the "in" keyword in my solution to avoid traversing my song set every iteration, all I use is the length of the set. Using len() actually doesn't require traversing the entire list, it actually runs at O(1) constant time! Here is my reference: [Cost of len() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function)

```
def is_repeating_playlist(self):
    song_set = {self}
    songs_traversed = 1
    current_song = self
    while True:
        next = current_song.next
        if next == None:
            return False
        if len(song_set) != songs_traversed:
            return True
        song_set.add(next)
        current_song = next
        songs_traversed += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it using the recursive function. Although I have to break the functions out when the condition is met as many as I call recursive functions.

```
class Song:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.next = None

def next_song(self, song):
    self.next = song

def is_repeating_playlist(self):
    first = self.name
    def recursion(self,first):
        if self.next == None:
            return False

        while not first == self.next.next.name:
            recursion(self.next, first)
            break
        print('break out')
        return True

    return recursion(self,first)


first = Song("Hello")
second = Song("Eye of the tiger")
third = Song("mamma mia!")
fourth = Song("lion king")

first.next_song(second)
second.next_song(third)
third.next_song(fourth)
fourth.next_song(first)

print(first.is_repeating_playlist())
```

Answer (score 0):

simple and straightforward

```
def is_repeating_playlist(self):
    songs = set()
    while self.next:
        if self.next.name in songs:
            return True
        else:
            songs.add(self.next.name)
            self.next = self.next.next or None

    return False
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be using a queue where last element links to the first element. To implement this update your class with `self.previous`

then your queue would look like (added third for clarity):

```
first = Song("Hello")
second = Song("Eye of the tiger")
third = Song("We are the champions")

first.next_song(second)
first.prev_song(third)

second.next_song(third)
second.prev_song(first)

third.next_song(first)
third.prev_song(second)
```