# What is the secret behind Python's len() builtin time complexity of O(1)

Tags: python, c, time-complexity

Since Python is implemented in C, I am confused how the developers managed to make the Python builtin `len` function run on any sequence in constant time, O(1), while C's string function `strlen` runs in linear time, O(n).

What is the secret behind Python's builtin `len` functions's time complexity? If we were to write program in C, would it be best practice to copy Python's code for `len` if we ever wanted to a fast C program involves sequence length?

Comment: It counts the elements as they are added and then returns the stored count.

Comment: You could build it this way but c is built for efficiency so it doesn’t store a count to save space.

Comment: Python strings are not *exactly* C strings. BTW, Python is free software, so you should download its source code and study it

Comment: @codekid it counts the elements as they are added? So, if I call len on a sequence (be it string, list, set, tuple, or other), does that mean it is making a copy of the object it is taking the length of?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I see, thank you. I should do that :)

Comment: Because the Python objects just keep track of their own size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cost of len() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function)

Comment: Thank @UVM but this is a different question. I already know the cost of `len()`. The cost of which I had already mentioned as O(1) constant time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess you are missing one concept that is how a data structure can return its size in constant time i.e. O(1).

Roughly, think of a program like this:

```
void init(){
     // code to initialize (or allocate memory) the container 
     size = 0;
}
void add(Something something){
     container.add(something);
     size++;
}
void remove(Something something){
   //Code to search 'something'
   if(found) { 
    container.remove(something); 
    size--;
   }
}
int len(){
    return size;
}
```

Now any time you call the method `len()`, it is ready to return the integral value **without any need to traverse** the `container`.

Why `strlen` or any C related data structure doesn't work that way is *because* of the space overhead of having a counter like `size`. But that doesn't mean you can't define one. 
*Hint:
Use struct and keep the size maintained there.*

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you for explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

Any string/list in python is an object. Like many objects, it has a `__len__` method, which stores the length of the list. When we call `len`, `__len__` gets called internally, and returns the stored value, which is an O(1) operation.

Comment: What it does not say is the cost of maintaining the length field as each operation to the object is made. This can overcome the actual total computer usage far more than C does.