# Time complexity of accessing collections.deque length

Tags: python, collections, deque

What is the time complexity of calling Python's built-in `len()` function on `collections.deque`? I expect it to be O(1), but I haven't found any confirmation of this fact.

Comment: At least in CPython, see [the defintion of `deque_len`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L1023), in which `Py_SIZE(deque)` is just a [macro around a field reference](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9bdd2de84c1af55fbc006d3f892313623bd0195c/Include/object.h#L128). I find it unlikely that another implementation would make it slower.

Comment: the answer is O(1): https://stackoverflow.com/a/1115382/10397775

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In CPython time complexity is O(1) indeed. This fact can be deduced by looking at the source code of CPython (look at chepner's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516216/time-complexity-of-accessing-collections-deque-length#comment97737322_55516216)).