# Algorithm to find max string length in a column

Tags: algorithm

I have a million rows and I need to find the max character length of a field. For example, the data might look like this:

```
[
  ['john doe', 12, 2.99],
  ['jane doe', 29, 3.99],
]
```

And to figure out the maxLength of the first column I would do:

```
maxLength = 0
for row in rows:
    maxLength = max(len(row[0]), maxLength)
```

However, determining the `len(str)` seems like an expensive operation. Is there a better way to do this, even perhaps approximating the max length, etc? An answer in python or C/C++ is fine -- I'm just looking for how it would be done.

Comment: I know little Python, but in modern C++ getting the length of a `std::string` is [guaranteed to be dirt cheap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size). A naive iteration through the list would be reasonable.

Comment: `len(str)` is [O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function). If you still don't want to use it, you can perform one pass through your rows and preprocess the length of each one, then your function wouldnt need to call `len(row[0])`, but some preprocessed value instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Python's built-in `max` with a key function using `len`, which is `O(1)` for strings as mentioned in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function):

```py
max_row = max(a, key = lambda r : len(r[0]))
```

Comment: It's max character length though, not the max value. But basically the question is more about if there's a better way to find the maximum string length in a row.

Comment: @David542 Yeah I just added `len`, which is `O(1)` by the way.