# Deciding whether a string is a palindrome

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

This is a python question. Answer should be with O(n) time complexity and use no additional memory. As input i get a string which should be classified as palindrome or not (palindrome is as word or a phrase that can be read the same from left to right and from right to left, f.e "level"). In the input there can be punctuation marks and gaps between words. 
For example "I. did,,, did I????" The main goal is to decide whether the input is a palindrome.

When I tried to solve this question i faced several challenges. When I try to delete non letter digits

```
for element in string:
    if ord(element) not in range(97, 122):
        string.remove(element)
    if ord(element) == 32:
        string.remove(element)
```

I use O(n^2) complexity, because for every element in the string i use remove function, which itself has O(n) complexity, where n is the length of the list. I need help optimizing the part with eliminating non letter characters with O(n) complexity

Also, when we get rid of spaces as punctuation marks I know how to check whether a word is a palindrome, but my method uses additional memory.

Comment: What is your overall approach to the problem? Why are you removing characters from the string, in particular?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel, I am removing non letter characters to simply have letters, so it is easier to decide whether it is a palindrome. I am open to methods, where it can be decided whether a phrase is a palindrome without removing non letter characters. Most important it has to be O(n) time complexity and use no additional memory. I just thought this way it will be easier

Comment: Why is there so much emphasis on no additional memory? Do you think removing a character from an immutable string doesn't create a new string?

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz, I know that removing a character from an immutable sting creates a new string - thats exactly why I want to work with lists instead

Comment: Your input will be given to you as a string, so any list you work with is also additional memory. If the question was posed to you this way, and the restriction is for teaching purposes, then I can guarantee that your instructor wants you to *not preprocess the data* in this way, but instead come up with an algorithm that simply ignores the non-letters while processing. Yes, it's not a realistic approach to the problem. Programming courses are like that.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, yes I understood, that he wants us to work with the strings, not lists

Comment: @vnikonov_63 the answer that you've accepted also creates a new list, hence additional memory! :)

Comment: Note that `range(97, 122)` does not include the letter `z`.

Comment: @user3386109, better range(97, 123)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your O(n) solution without creating a new string:

```
def is_palindrome(string):
    left = 0
    right = len(string) - 1

    while left < right:
        if not string[left].isalpha():
            left += 1
            continue
        if not string[right].isalpha():
            right -= 1
            continue

        if string[left] != string[right]:
            return False

        left += 1
        right -= 1

    return True


print(is_palindrome("I. did,,, did I????"))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: but this uses extra memory, when we declare right and left

Comment: @vnikonov_63 "no extra memory" usually means O(1) on memory, so single loop variables don't count

Comment: @vnikonov_63 Every program uses O(1) extra memory. There's no way to avoid that. The answer you accepted is using O(n) extra memory, because list comprehension creates a list.

Comment: I agree with @user3386109, there is no way you can know that a string is a palindrome without iterating over it. That's why you require pointers for iteration and you can't avoid that.

Comment: How is `len()` determined ? Wouldn't it require traversing the entire string ?

Comment: @Niloct in CPython it's O(1), which is the most common implementation of Python. You can read more about it here: [Cost of len() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function)

Comment: @Niloct and even if it's O(n), still the overall time complexity of this algorithm would be O(n).

Comment: Space complexity actually refers to how your storage will react based on the inputs and how extra storage is being used in an algorithm. For instance, the palindrome string could be of length 2 or 50. However, for this algorithm, the two-pointer variables will remain 2, no matter what. That means they are constant, thus, space complexity will be O(1).

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you mean you want to test if a string is a palindrome when we remove all punctuation digits from the string. In that case, the following code should suffice:

```
from string import ascii_letters

def is_palindrome(s):
    s = ''.join(c for c in s if c in ascii_letters)
    return s == s[::-1]

# some test cases:
print(is_palindrome('hello'))  # False
print(is_palindrome('ra_ceca232r'))  # True
```

Comment: Aren't we using additional memory, when declare s? Or we are just revising it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner using [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) syntax (Python 3.8+):

```
>>> s =  "I. did,,, did I????"
>>> (n := [c.lower() for c in s if c.isalpha()]) == n[::-1]
True
```

---

I mostly showed the above as a demonstration; for readability's sake I'd recommend something more like SimonR's solution (although still using `isalpha` over comparing to `ascii_letters`).

Alternatively, you can use [generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to do the same comparison without allocating `O(n)` extra memory:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    forward = (c.lower() for c in s if c.isalpha())
    back = (c.lower() for c in reversed(s) if c.isalpha())
    return all(a == b for a, b in zip(forward, back))
```

Note that `zip` still allocates in Python 2, you'll need to use `itertools.izip` there.

Comment: abuse of string comprehensions and obscure language features is never a good thing

Comment: Abuse is a pretty strong term. And assignment expressions are a new feature, the only way to leave obscurity is if people use it!

Answer (score 0):

## Will this help:

```
word = input('Input your word: ')
word1 = ''
for l in word:
    if l.isalnum():
        word1 += l
word2=''
for index in sorted(range(len(word1)),reverse=True):
    word2+=word1[index]
if word1 == word2:
    print('It is a palindrone.')
else:
    print('It is not a palindrone.')
```

Comment: Here you use additional memory, when declare word2 = ' '

Comment: This is a bad implementation considering the runtime and space complexity. First of all, you are concatenating string that takes O(XN^2). Moreover, you are also sorting the list that takes O(N log N).

Comment: This code has a bug such that `"aaa"` is a palindrome but `"a?aa"` isn't.  This is due to missing parentheses on `if l.isalnum:` -- i.e. it should be `if l.isalnum():` as you're testing the existence of the method rather than the result of calling it.