# Python, not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' error

Tags: python

here is my function

```
def find_short(s):
    s = s.split()
    max = len(s[0])
    for i in s:
        if len(i) <= max:
            max = i
    return max

    print(find_short("bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps"))
```

What is incorrect here?

Comment: Please format your code to be valid Python code (now e.g. `def ...` and `s = ...` has the same intendation)

Comment: You should do **max = len(i)** rather than **max = i** because **i** is a string in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten to add some `len`  to `i` in your `for` loop. See my anser that corrects this error.

```
def find_short(s):
    s = s.split()
    if not s:
       return 0,""
    max = len(s[0])
    argmax = s[0]
    for i in s:
        if len(i) <= max:
            max = len(i)
            argmax = i
    return max,argmax

print(find_short("bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps"))
(3, 'who')
```

Comment: Thanks dude helped me a lot

Comment: I've add an `if statement` to handle the `empty` string case. Programming is about thinking of all the worst cases :) .

Comment: Since we are in the Python > 3.8 era, I would suggest using the walrus operator (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/walrus-operator-in-python-3-8/) to avoid calling `len()` twice. `if (n := len(i)) <= max:` ... `max = n`

Comment: Calling `len` [cost nothing in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function), at least when it comes to builtin types like `list objects`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `max = i` line makes the `max` variable a `string`. You can not compare the `string` and the `int` value. That comes from you assigning the `i` which is an element of `s` variable to the `max`.

Comment: yeah I will but it says after 8minutes

Answer (score 0):

In the above code you have made two errors,

- using max, max is an inbuilt function of python so use some other name like maxi.
- at last after the first condition check in the if class, if the condition satisfies the max (which u used) will get updated with the string i, if you want to print small letter in the string use the following code.

  ```
   def find_short(s):
       s = s.split()
       maxi = len(s[0])
       for i in s:
           if len(i) <= maxi:
               maxi = len(i)
               ans = i
       return len(ans)
   print(find_short("bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps"))
  ```

  or else if you want to print length of small letter in the string use the following code.

  ```
   def find_short(s):
       s = s.split()
       maxi = len(s[0])
       for i in s:
           if len(i) <= maxi:
               maxi = len(i)
               ans = i
       return len(ans)
   print(find_short("bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps"))
  ```