# How to change data in the container while iterating in python

Tags: python

Given the following example:

```
container = [ (1, "a") , 
              (40, "b") ,
              (24, "c") ,  #we intend to change this
              (103, "d")
            ]

for k,v in container:
    if k == 24:
        v += " good"

print container
```

The ***(24, "c")*** data pair in ***container*** will still remain its original value, 
and won't be changed to ***(24, "c good")***. What would be the way to alter it to ***(24, "c good")*** as intended during the iteration?

I use python 2.7 , but 3.x examples are also welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating

Comment: v isn't a pointer, and tuples are immutable. The second point is the important one, and the reason all of the correct answers replace the entire tuple and not just the single value.

Comment: If you intend to change the values, you should probably avoid using immutable container (tuple) in the first place.  Perhaps a dict would be preferable here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) the keep track of the index of the container item you are looking at:

```
for i, (k,v) in enumerate(container):
    if k == 24:
        container[i] = (k, v+" good")
```

Answer (score 1):

Messed up a bit. Fixed now

```
container = [ (1, "a") , 
                  (40, "b") ,
                  (24, "c") ,  #we intend to change this
                  (103, "d")
                ]

for k, n in enumerate(container):
    if n[0] == 24:
        container[k] = (n[0], n[1] + " good")

print container
```

Comment: That doesn't work because `n` is a tuple and `container[n]` doesn't make sense (In Python's words: "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple")

Comment: You can not index container with n like that.

Comment: Sorry for that, fixed now. Was thinking about dicts when I wrote that.

Comment: better, but now it identical to sth already provided answer, so you should delete this answer.