# Strange behavior of os.walk() in Python?

Tags: python, os.walk

This is the original block of code and its result:

Code:

```
if os.path.isdir(top):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown = True):
        for dirname in dirs:
            print 'Dirname = ', os.path.join(root, dirname)
```

Results:

```
Dirname = ../output/.svn
Dirname = ../output/a random folder
Dirname = ../output/a random folder - copy
Dirname = ../output/.svn\pristine
Dirname = ../output/.svn\temp
Dirname = ../output/.svn\pristine\04
Dirname = ../output/.svn\pristine\59
Dirname = ../output/a random folder\another one inside
Dirname = ../output/a random folder\another one inside - Copy
Dirname = ../output/a random folder\another one inside - Copy (2)
```

Now I want to ignore all hidden folders and subfolders. This is the modified code and its result:

Code:

```
if os.path.isdir(top):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown = True):
        for dirname in dirs:
            print 'Dirname = ', os.path.join(root, dirname)
            if dirname.startswith('.'):
                dirs.remove(dirname)
```

Result:

```
Dirname = ../output/.svn
Dirname = ../output/a random folder - copy
Dirname = ../output/a random folder\another one inside
Dirname = ../output/a random folder\another one inside - Copy
Dirname = ../output/a random folder\another one inside - Copy (2)
```

What I don't understand is: why is ../output/a random folder not listed anymore??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not modify an iterable while you're iterating over it. In this case, you're modifying `dirs` inside of a `for` loop that iterates over `dirs`.

Try this instead:

```
if os.path.isdir(top):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown = True):
        dirs_to_ignore = []
        for dirname in dirs:
            print 'Dirname = ', os.path.join(root, dirname)
            if dirname.startswith('.'):
                dirs_to_ignore.append(dirname)
        for dirname in dirs_to_ignore:
            dirs.remove(dirname)
```

See also: [Modifying list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Your diagnosis is correct, but I think you've missed the point of the original code. It really does mean to remove items from `dirs` so that `os.walk` won't recurse into those directories. A more correct fix would be to copy `dirs` and iterate over the copy while removing items from the original.

Comment: I changed my code example to reflect the intent of the original code. I did it by keeping a temporary list of directories to ignore, and then pruning them from `dirs`. Weeble's suggestion of iterating over a copy and removing from the original should also work.

Comment: Making a `dirs_to_keep` list followed by `dirs[:] = dirs_to_keep` would be shorter and more efficient, though performance really does not matter here.

Comment: Jochen, can you give an example? I don't really get your comment.