# Temporary created during python list iteration?

Tags: python, list, iteration

I want to understand why the following is happening. My guess is that a temporary is being created during list iteration, but want some experts to confirm this:

```
def test():
    a=[set([1,2,3]),set([3,4,5])]
    x=set([1,4])
    for i in a:
        # doesn't actually modify list contents, making a copy of list elements in i?
        i=i.difference(x)
    print a
    for idx,i in enumerate(a):
        i=i.difference(x)
        print id(i),id(a[idx])
        # obviously this modifies the contents
        a[idx]=i
    print a
```

Output:

```
[set([1, 2, 3]), set([3, 4, 5])]
59672976 59672616
59672616 59672736
[set([2, 3]), set([3, 5])]
```

Also, I want to understand why the "id" of i in the second iteration is the same as the "id" for a[0].

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating

Comment: @Series8217 I already saw this one but that is more about modified the actual sequence itself while iterating whereas I'm talking about modifying the contents of the sequence. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take this one step at a time:

1. `i.difference(x)` doesn't modify `i` or `x`. Rather, it returns a new set.
2. `i = i.difference(x)` *rebinds* the variable `i` to point to the new set. It does not affect the contents of the list in any way.
3. `a[idx] = i` does modify the list by setting its `idx`-th element to the new set.

A cleaner implementation might use a different variable instead of re-purposing `i`:

```
def test():
    a=[set([1,2,3]),set([3,4,5])]
    x=set([1,4])
    for i in a:
        diff=i.difference(x)
        # a[idx]=diff
    print a
```

Comment: So i is a temporary, a copy of one of the elements of the sequence, right?

Comment: @Sid: In Python there's no such thing as a *temporary* (in the C++ sense). What your code does is **reuse** the variable called `i` to store the result of `i.difference(x)`. See my updated answer for a cleaner way to code the same thing.

Comment: Actually, LCs and genexes *do* produce a sort of temporary.

Comment: @aix Can you take a look at my update regarding the "id" of "i" vs. that of a[0]? Is that what you mean by "reuse"?

Comment: @Sid: no, it's a reference to one of the elements in the sequence.  If this element happens to be a mutable object, you can modify it in place.  For example, suppose `i` was a list, then `i.append(1)` would append 1 to the list that's inside the set.  Assigning to `i` only re-binds the name `i` to another object.  The confusion arises from the fact that for immutable objects such as integers, there is no perceived difference between assignment and mutation.

Answer (score 4):

It helps to look at this graphically, because it's basically a pointer problem.

`for i in a` iteratively assigns `i` to each element in `a`.

[image: iteration]

`i = i.difference(x)` creates [image: new object] and assigns `i` to it.

[image: assignment]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when you execute `i=i.difference(x)` it creates a new `i`. Just modify your code like this to understand what is happening -

```
def test():
    a=[set([1,2,3]),set([3,4,5])]
    x=set([1,4])
    for i in a:
        # doesn't actually modify list contents, making a copy of list elements in i?
        print 'old i - ', id(i)
        i=i.difference(x)
        print 'new i - ', id(i)
    print a

test()
```

Output -

```
old i -  4467059736
new i -  4467179216
old i -  4467177360
new i -  4467179216
[set([1, 2, 3]), set([3, 4, 5])]
```

Comment: I added the line print id(i),id(a[idx]) and got the following ids:
59672976 59672616
59672616 59672736
So obviously the ids are different for i vs. the corresponding a[idx] but what I found weird was that the id for a[0] got assigned to i in the next iteration. Maybe this is what @aix means by reuse?

Answer (score 1):

Your use of set.difference() suggests that you don't know the operator `-=` for sets:

```
def test():
    a=[set([1,2,3]),set([3,4,5])]
    x=set([1,4])
    for i in a:
        i -= x
    print a
```

This shows that `i` is just another pointer to the set you want to modify.  Just don't overwrite your pointer!

Comment: I find this semantically bizarre that i-=x actually modifies the pointee while i=i-x modifies the pointer. Traditionally one would expect i-=x and i=i-x to be equivalent, no?

Comment: @Sid `=` is the assignment operator. `-=` is an "augmented" assignment, which evaluates the target only once, and modifies it in-place where possible. Refer to the documentation for [augmented assignment expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements).

Comment: There's a good reason why the two syntaxes `i = i - x` and `i -= x` have also different methods (namely `__sub__()` and `__isub__()` ;-)

Comment: @Series8217 Thanks, that section was very helpful.