# "for item in list" - where does the None item come from?

Tags: python

i got this list of objects with one item in it.

```
    print self.parameters
    print len(self.parameters)
    for p in self.parameters:
        print p
```

when i print out the list and len of the lsit i see the expected: one item.
But when looping over the lsit i also get a None item...!?

```
[<__main__.Parameter object at 0x00000000022D4828>]
1
<__main__.Parameter object at 0x00000000022D4828>
None
```

what is going on here?
(yes im sure, that the "None" output is from this print statement)

---

EDIT:
i was manipulating the list i was looping over:

```
print self.parameters
print len(self.parameters)
for p in self.parameters:
    print p
    (...)
    self.parameters.append(<something that returned None>)
```

Comment: is this inside a function ... ? are you saying `print self.doSomething()` somewhere else?

Comment: There's no other prints in the program after this loop that could be doing this?

Comment: Also is it possible to create a full, minimal program that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this.

```
for p in self.parameters:
    print p
    ...
    self.parameters.append(...) # No.
```

See [Modifying list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating) -- basically, you shouldn't modify something while iterating over it.  You can make a copy if you want:

```
for p in list(self.parameters):
    print p
    ...
    self.parameters.append(...) # Okay
```