# Change List which is iterated over

Tags: coding-style

I heard that it is not good style to change a list which you are iterating over within the iteration.

Example (pseudo code):

```
for (int i = 0; i < someList.length(); i++) {
  someList.getAt(i).doSomething();
}
```

Why is that? Could there be any side effects?

Comment: This depends on the language, at least in part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a copy. Change that, iterate around the original.

Otherwise the iterator won't know about changes made. More here:

[Modifying list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be better.

```
for_each(E item in somelist)
{
     item.doSomeThing();
}
```

E/Item could be anything(customers, ints, doubles)

Comment: what exactly is the advantage of for_each compared to for?

Comment: Well you do not have to call getAt(i) each time. This would speed things up a little more.