# Regex matching non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Python to parse some strings in a list. Some of the strings may only contain non-alphanumeric characters which I'd like to ignore, like this:

```
list = ['()', 'desk', 'apple', ':desk', '(house', ')', '(:', ')(', '(', ':(', '))']

for item in list:
    if re.search(r'\W+', item):
        list.remove(item)

# Ideal output
list = ['desk', 'apple', ':desk', '(house']

# Actual output
list = ['desk', 'apple', '(:', '(', '))']
```

That's my first attempt at the regex for this problem, but it's not really having the desired effect. How would I write a regex to ignore any strings with non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: What result do you expect? This seems to be correct, as the two strings with non-alphanumeric characters have been removed.

Comment: Hmm, I may have misread, but I took your question to be that you only want to exclude strings which are only non-alphanumeric, i.e. you want to leave a string like '(apple)' in the list. Is that correct?

Comment: I've updated my example to show what I'm getting, versus what I'd like.

Answer (score 6):

BTW your Regex seems to match non-alphanumeric characters. However it isn't **advisable** to remove items from a list your currently iterating over and that's the cause of this error **therefore** to overcome this create a new list and append to it the elements which don't match.

[image]

Demo:

```
import re

list = ['()', 'desk', 'apple', ':desk', '(house', ')', '(:', ')(', '(', ':(', '))']
new_list = []

for item in list:
    if not re.search(r'^\W+$', item) or re.search(r'^\w+', item) :
        new_list.append(item)

print new_list
```

Produces:

```
['desk', 'apple', ':desk', '(house']
```

As far as I tested this works in nearly all scenarios.

Comment: \W == [^\w] by definition

Comment: Thats what I said @njzk2

Answer (score 2):

What about a list comprehension with `re.match(pattern, string)`:

```
import re

items = ['()', 'desk', 'apple', ')', '(:', ')(', '(', ':(', '))']
cleaned_items = [item for item in items if re.match('\W?\w+', item)]
print cleaned_items
```

This prints

```
['desk', 'apple', ':desk', '(house']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your regex. You are iterating over a list which you are then modifying, which causes weirdness (see [Modifying list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating)).  You can use a list comprehension like Jon posted, or you can iterate over a copy of the list: `for item in list[:]:`

Comment: The problem is also with the regex. Based on the OP's edited question, they want a regex which will match strings that consist _only_ of non-alphanumeric characters.