# Trying to remove multiples of integers in list from another, receiving "out of index" error

Tags: python, list, loops

```
K = int(input())
m = int(input())
a = []
c = []
for i in range (1, K+1):
    a.append(i)
for i in range(m):
    b = int(input())
    c.append(b)

for j in a:
    for i in c:
        if a[j] % c[i] == 0:
             a.remove(a[j])
print(a)
```

Currently giving me a index out of range error, but I don't see whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

You're modifying a list while iterating over it.  Generally speaking, that's not a good idea.

The root problem is the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1637807/748858) (and many others that you could find by searching Stack Overflow).

---

Additionally, you're using the items in the list as the indices instead of the items themselves.  You probably meant:

```
for j in a:
    for i in c:
        if j % i == 0:
            ...
```

Comment: *and* using the contents as indices, instead of `i` and `j` directly.