# Can I append an element to a list that is currently being processed in a for loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I'd like to simply know if this does not lead the program to errors.

```
for a in b:
    if <condition>:
        b = b + [something]
```

Comment: why dont you try this?

Comment: FWIW: You are not "appending". You're creating a new list from the combination of `b` and `[something]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifying list while iterating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating) (Assuming you really want to append, instead of recreating a new list)

Comment: `b[:] = b + [x]` would modify the original list and also create an infinite loop `for x in b[:]:b[:] = b + [something]` would do what you want but so would extend

Comment: What data are you trying to act upon? you are taking and element from the list but not using it for anything.