# Why does this loop never get past the first item in the list?

Tags: python, list

I have a function that is supposed to increment each element in the odd rows of a matrix by 5, and each element in the even rows by 10.  I have written the code below:

```
def incrementRows(matrix):
    for i in matrix:
        print(matrix.index(i))

        if matrix.index(i) % 2 == 0:
            matrix[matrix.index(i)] = [x + 5 for x in matrix[matrix.index(i)]]
        else:
            matrix[matrix.index(i)] = [x + 10 for x in matrix[matrix.index(i)]]


    return matrix


matrix = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]

print(incrementRows(matrix))
```

The problem with this code, is that judging by the print(matrix.index(i)) statement in the function, the loop never passes the first item in the list.  I cannot understand why.  Below is the output:

```
0
0
0
[[16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

If I take the If/else statements out of the function, then the loop will iterate through each item in the list properly.

```
def incrementRows(matrix):
    for i in matrix:
        print(matrix.index(i))

    return matrix


matrix = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]

print(incrementRows(matrix))
```

Result:

```
0
1
2
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Can anybody tell me why the If/else statements in the function are preventing the loop from iterating through each item in the list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifying list while iterating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating)

Comment: `index()` returns the position of a value in a list, this doesn't _seem_ to be what you want. What happens if you replace `matrix.index(i)` with just `i`?

Comment: If you need `i` to be index of the matrix instead of the value at that index, you can use `enumerate`, e.g. `for i, row in enumerate(matrix): print(i, row)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your given data, you're changing the matrix at each step to ensure what was the next item in it is always found at index 0.

To check that, change

```
print(matrix.index(i))
```

to

```
print(i, matrix, matrix.index(i))
```

and you'll see the much more informative output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]] 0
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10] [[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]] 0
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15] [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]] 0
```

See?  Each time, you're changing the 0th index so it equals the next item in the matrix.

Looping on a list's items and then doing an `.index` of each item on the list, of course, will always find the **first** occurrence of a copy of each item -- besides wasting a lot of computation in any case (making a loop O(N squared) that should of course be O(N)) this will provoke truly weird results in cases like yours.

To get back to sanity, change the part:

```
def incrementRows(matrix):
    for i in matrix:
        print(matrix.index(i))
```

to, e.g

```
def incrementRows(matrix):
    for where in range(len(matrix)):
        print(where)
```

and use `where` throughout the rest wherever you're now re-computing (wasting ridiculous numbers of cycles) `matrix.index(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on the second iteration, the first and second items compare equal, so index just gives you the first one again.

I believe it's time for you to learn about [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). Basically here `i` is just the index without having to scan the list for matches over and over.

```
def incrementRows(matrix):
    for i, item in enumerate(matrix):
        print(i)

        if i % 2 == 0:
            matrix[i] = [x + 5 for x in item]
        else:
            matrix[i] = [x + 10 for x in item]


    return matrix


matrix = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]

print(incrementRows(matrix))
```

The code is much easier to read and it works properly now

Comment: A note, the OP's original code has their cases backwards since it's supposed to add 10 to *even* rows, which would be when `i%2==0`.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be much more straight-forward here to use a list-comp, and base the modulus on the "row number" that you're iterating over inside a conditional expression to choose either to add 5 or 10, eg:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]
result = [
    [n + 5 if rowno % 2 == 0 else n + 10 for n in row] 
    for rowno, row in enumerate(matrix)
]
# [[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]
```

Comment: A note, the OP's original code has their cases backwards since it's supposed to add 10 to *even* rows, which would be when `i%2==0`.

Comment: @aruisdante I was pondering that - I admit I went with the logic in the OPs code instead of the reading properly the previous sentence though... I'm sure the OP can manage to swap the numbers around easily enough :p

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're modifying the structure of a list while iterating over it. [Don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating).

But I think you do that because you don't realize what this does:

```
for i in matrix:
    print(matrix.index(i))
```

I don't know if you realize this, but `i` is going to be *the element in the list at that loop in the iteration*. An example:

```
matrix = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
for row in matrix:
    print(row)
```

Outputs:

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
[5,6]
```

And `matrix.index(i)` is going to result in the index of the 'value' `i` in the list `matrix` using a simple linear search.

If you want a "c-style" for-loop over an index, you'd do it like so:

```
for i in xrange(len(matrix)): # Use just range(len(matrix)) if python 3.X
    print(matrix[i])
```

However, python has a nifty method, `enumerate`, which will give us both the index and the value at a location in an iterator.

In which case your code would become the following:

```
def increment_rows(matrix):
    for i,row in enumerate(matrix):
        print(i,row)
        matrix[i] = [v + 5 for v in row] if i % 2 else [v + 10 for v in row]
    print(matrix)
    return matrix
```

Which will result in the output you want. Of course you can actually collapse this into a single one-liner list comp leveraging `enumerate`:

```
def increment_rows(matrix):
    return [([v + 5 for v in row] if i % 2 else [v + 10 for v in row]) for i,row in enumerate(matrix)]
```

Comment: Actually, the OP is **not** modifying the **structure** -- he's modifying fixed-places **items** within the list, which is just fine.  He's wrong in a completely different way -- the use (and over-use) of `matrix.index(i)`.