# change bounds of range function when it is running without stopping it

Tags: python

if I have a python script as below:

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(60)
```

When it is running to count `3` now,
is it possible to change to upper limit from `10` to `20`?

---

To make it clear, I mean without stopping the running process.
I want to change it to make it run to `20`.

Say, maybe modify `/dev/mem` or `/proc/pid/something` ?

Comment: No not when the code is running

Comment: if it's not running. `for j in range(10, 20):`

Comment: What is the exact question and how does it relate the sample code posted by you ? Please be little more descriptive.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: [The documentation makes it pretty clear that it's in seconds.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep)

Comment: @user2357112 My mistake, I'm confusing my languages.

Comment: does my solution work for you?

Comment: Sorry, I added some on my question, I am asking if we don't stop the process, I think it is not about Python but Linux

Comment: is the question about if you can manipulate stack in python ? just as you could do in a lower level language ..say C ?

Comment: no, I mean when the process is running, can I modify anything in Linux that make `10` become `20`, so that the process can run to `20`?

Answer (score 1):

Another name for a `for` loop is fixed repetition. Fixed means that you can not change constraints.

```
var = 0
cap = 10

while var < cap:
    var += 1
    action()

    if var == 3:
        cap = 20
```

Comment: Where `action` is anything you wish to do, like `print` and `sleep`

Comment: 'can not change constraints' what does exactly mean?

Comment: @NizamMohamed `for` iterates an iterable which can not be changed during iteration.

Comment: 'changed' means what? insertion, removal or appending. And why?

Comment: @NizamMohamed See [here](https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/) for a great explanation.

Comment: @NizamMohamed This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating)  will help you as well. What do you think?

Comment: [for loop](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) only talks about insertion and removal. Appending and extending list works ok.

Comment: Yes, appending and extending is okay, but very bad practice. It is simply inefficient compared to while loop any way for this particular purpose.

Answer (score 0):

`range` returns a `list` in Python 2, so if it's stored which can be extended.

```
range_list = range(10)
for i in range_list:
    print(i)
    if i == 3:
        range_list.extend(range(10,20))
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: I'd like to know why I got a downvote so that I can improve.

Comment: Yours only works because you're modifying at the end so the start of the list remains the same. Otherwise, changing a list while iterating is bad practice.