# Remove a tuple from a list if the tuple contains a certain element by given index

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples (num, id):

```
l = [(1000, 1), (2000, 2), (5000, 3)]
```

The second element of each tuple contains the identifier. Say that I want to remove the tuple with the id of `2`, how do I do that?

I.e. I want the new list to be: `l = [(1000,1), (5000, 3)]`

I have tried `l.remove(2)` but it won't work.

Comment: I thought to let you know. In case you want to remove element from the existing list, choose among the answers which are using `pop()` or `remove()` function. If you want to create new list based on filtered logic, choose among the remaining one.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri ayyyyyyyyyyyyyy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with a filter to achieve this.

```
l = [(1000, 1), (2000, 2), (5000, 3)]
m = [(val, key) for (val, key) in l if key != 2]
```

Comment: It will work. But the question was to remove element from the list, but you are creating the new list

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri That is because an iterable such as a list should not be mutated whilst iterating over its contents, so the standard solution is to create a new list using a conditional list comprehension. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating

Comment: @Alexander I agree with you regarding the mutation part. But in this case, based on the requirement; ideal way I believe is to iterate over the copy of list and remove elements from the original list.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I strongly disagree.  You could do a reassignment, e.g. `l = [tup for tup in l if tup[1] != 2]`.

Comment: @Alexander: The answer to this will be based on one's perception. My view is based on the question asked `Remove a tuple from a list`. If this was not mentioned in the question, even I would be in favour of this answer. PS: I haven't down-voted (nor up-voted) this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Or using filter:

```
l = [(1000, 1), (2000, 2), (5000, 3)]
print(list(filter(lambda x: x[1] != 2, l)))
```

output:

```
[(1000, 1), (5000, 3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the value **2** is not in the list.  Instead, something like the below: form a list of the second elements in your tuples, then remove the element at that position.

```
del_pos = [x[1] for x in l].index(2)
l.pop(del_pos)
```

Note that this removes only the first such element.  If your instance is not unique, then use one of the other solutions.  I believe that this is faster, but handles only the single-appearance case.

Answer (score 1):

Simple list comprehension:

```
[x for x in l if x[1] != 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do it with:

```
>>> l = [(1000, 1), (2000, 2), (5000, 3)]
>>> for i in list(l):
...     if i[1] == 2:
...         l.remove(i)
```

In case you want to remove only first occurence, add `break` below `remove` line

Comment: This method is also much slower. ```from random import seed, randint

seed(0)
l = [(randint(1, 1000), randint(1, 5)) for _ in range(10000)]

%time l2 = [tup for tup in l if tup[1] != 2]
CPU times: user 8.38 ms, sys: 1.97 ms, total: 10.3 ms
Wall time: 8.7 ms

%%time
for i in list(l):
    if i[1] == 2:
        l.remove(i)
CPU times: user 285 ms, sys: 3.69 ms, total: 289 ms
Wall time: 285 ms```

Answer (score 0):

One more possible solution

```
r = [(1000, 1), (2000, 2), (5000, 3)]
t = [i for i in r if i.count(2) == 0]
```