# Issue when removing false from list with isinstance

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, boolean

So, I was messing around removing non-integers from a list in Python (very exciting stuff). I came across an issue with the following code that I cannot seem to resolve:

```
list_a = ["a", 1, 2, 3, False, [1, 2, 3]]

for item in list_a:
    if not isinstance(item, int):
        list_a.remove(item)
```

I'm trying to remove all non int items in the list but the the above code does not remove False.

**What I want: `[1, 2, 3]`**

**What I'm getting: `[1, 2, 3, False]`**

Any help figuring this out would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check out http://pythontutor.com

Comment: False is a value, which is 0, which is an integer!

Comment: `False` is internally represented as an integer number 0. In fact `False==0` is `True` - but `False is 0` is not. Use operator `is` to remove `False`.

Comment: Other issue: you're shifting items around in a list while iterating over it. Don't do that. Build a new list.

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is that [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) *is* a subclass of `int`:

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

Therefore, all bools are ints (where False is 0 and True is 1) and could be used for indexing and such. You can test `type(item) is bool` instead.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, `bool` is a subclass of `int`:

```
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>> isinstance(True, bool)
True
```

This means that you need a more refined check. You could, for example, check that `type(item) == int`.

For background, see [PEP 285](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/):

```
    6) Should bool inherit from int?

    => Yes.

       In an ideal world, bool might be better implemented as a
       separate integer type that knows how to perform mixed-mode
       arithmetic.  However, inheriting bool from int eases the
       implementation enormously (in part since all C code that calls
       PyInt_Check() will continue to work -- this returns true for
       subclasses of int).  Also, I believe this is right in terms of
       substitutability: code that requires an int can be fed a bool
       and it will behave the same as 0 or 1.  Code that requires a
       bool may not work when it is given an int; for example, 3 & 4
       is 0, but both 3 and 4 are true when considered as truth
       values.
```

Another, unrelated, issue is that you're modifying a list while iterating over it. Have a read of [Modifying list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating) and links therein.

This results in a subtle bug in your code. For example, it fails to remove `"b"` from the following list (try it!):

```
list_a = ["a", "b", 1, 2, 3]

for item in list_a:
    if not isinstance(item, int):
        list_a.remove(item)
```

One clean way to fix this is by using a list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

Check not if an item is an instance of something. Check its type directly:

```
[x for x in list_a if type(x)==int]
```

> [1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 1):

You are making two errors here:

- Assuming `isinstance` works with `bool` (others have explained how `bool` actually sub-classes from `int`).
- Altering a list while you iterate through it

This may be one of those cases where explicitly testing using `type(val) == int` is warranted:

```
list_a = ["a", 1, 2, 3, False, [1, 2, 3]]

for item in list_a[:]:
    if not type(item) == int:
        list_a.remove(item)
```

which yields the wanted result; notice how `list_a` is copied with `[:]` assuring we iterate over all its contents despite removing from it.

In a comprehension form, this is prettier:

```
res = [i for i in list_a if type(i) == int]
```

Answer (score 1):

A clear way to do it.

```
list_a = ["a", 1, 2, 3, False, [1, 2, 3]]
list_b = []
for item in list_a:
    if isinstance(item, int) and not isinstance(item, bool):
        list_b.append(item)
print list_b
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Bool is a subclass of Int, furthermore type() and isinstance() should not be confused. This is because before boolean became its own class "1"s and "0"s represented True and False respectively.

As a result you should use type() due to inheritance.

```
def f(randomList):
    result = []
    for elem in randomList:
        if type(elem)==int:
            result.append(elem)
    return result
```

This is a *non-destructive modified list* because sometimes modifying a list you're iterating through can cause errors or be a pain at least.