# Modifying a string within a list with a string method - stumped

Tags: python, list, function

I'm having an issue trying to modify strings within a list. I have a for loop set up to select each string item but I'm not able to modify it. I thought it might be a global/local scope issue or a muteable/immutable type issue but I've looked through documentation and I can't find out why I wouldn't be able to modify the string with the code I have in place right now.

The little program is not complete but the idea is to take my tableData variable and print it to look like

```
  apples Alice  dogs
 oranges   Bob  cats
cherries Carol moose
  banana David goose
```

This is a problem I've been on for a combined 5 hours, and its from Automate the Boring Stuff with Python chapter 6 practice project found at: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter6/

Here is my code (issue being at the very bottom):

```
# This program will take a list of string lists and print a table of the strings.

from copy import deepcopy
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]


def print_table():
'''This function will take any list of lists and print it in a table format
with evenly spaced columns.'''
    # First I wanted to identify the max length of my columns without making changes to my original list
    copied_list = deepcopy(tableData)  
    for copied_innerlist in range(len(copied_list)):
        copied_list[copied_innerlist].sort(key=len, reverse=True)  # sort each inner list by length
    colWidths = [len(copied_innerlist[0]) for copied_innerlist in copied_list]  # change the column width variable to reflect the length of longest string in each inner list

    # Now that I've stored my columns widths I want to apply them to all the strings without affecting the original
    final_list = deepcopy(tuple(tableData))

    for item in range(len(final_list)):
        for inner_item in final_list[item]:
            inner_item = inner_item.rjust(colWidths[item])
            '''WHY WONT THIS RJUST METHOD STICK '''


    print(final_list)
    """this just looks like that original list! :( """

print_table()
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, strings are [immutable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-immutable). When you do

```
inner_item = inner_item.rjust(colWidths[item])
```

you're just creating a *new string* and making the same label reference it. The old value (stored in the list) remains unchanged. You need to either modify list elements using indices:

```
for i in range(len(final_list)):
    for j in range(len(final_list[i])):
        final_list[i][j] = final_list[i][j].rjust(colWidths[i])
```

Or, better yet, build a new list using a list comprehension:

```
final_list = [inner_item.rjust(colWidths[item])
              for item in tableData for inner_item in item]
```

The latter is not only more concise, but also exempts you from the need to copy the original list.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify the strings in your `tableData` with `str.rjust` (you can easily avoid that **painful** `deepcopy`). I suggest you apply string formatting for printing:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

def print_table(data):
    lens = [max(map(len, x)) for x in data]  # get max length per column        
    lst = zip(*data)                         # transpose table
    for x in lst:
        print("{:>{l[0]}} {:>{l[1]}} {:>{l[2]}}".format(*x, l=lens))

print_table(tableData)
```

---

```
  apples Alice  dogs
 oranges   Bob  cats
cherries Carol moose
  banana David goose
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
         ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
         ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]


new = list(map(list, zip(*tableData)))

for i in new:
    print i
```

Output:

```
['apples', 'Alice', 'dogs']
['oranges', 'Bob', 'cats']
['cherries', 'Carol', 'moose']
['banana', 'David', 'goose']
```

Answer (score -1):

That is one of the reasons why you do not modify a loop while iterating it. It can lead to problems if you try to change and compute the iterables inside the loop simultaneously as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637875/5727175).

> Never alter the container you're looping on, because iterators on that container are not going to be informed of your alterations and, as you've noticed, that's quite likely to produce a very different loop and/or an incorrect one.

If you still want to do it, access it using index like this:

```
for item in range(len(final_list)):
        for index,inner_item in enumerate(final_list[item]):
            final_list[item][index] = inner_item.rjust(colWidths[item])
```

This one will work. Hope this helps!

Comment: So this is just a best practice then to not be changing items with for loops? Not sure I understood you correctly - I think I was just modifying a list while iterating over it and didnt expect it to be wrong!  I just got frustrated because I wasn't taught zip(), map() or list comprehensions yet so I was trying to use the skills I had. I did use a list comprehension near the start of my function but I didnt fully understand it even after the videos I watched on it