# Remove Stopwords from List and Read to TXT with NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

y'all. I've been trying to remove stopwords from a list that a pdf has been read to, but whenever I use nltk to remove those stopwords from the list or from a new list, it returns the original list back to me in the TXT file. I have made a separate program just to test if the stopwords function even works, and it works fine there but for some reason not in this case.

Is there also a better method to do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import PyPDF2 as pdf

import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stopping_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

stop_words = list(stopping_words)

# creating an object 
file = open("C:\\Users\\Name\\Documents\\Data Analytics Club\\SampleBook-English2-Reading.pdf", "rb")

# creating a pdf reader object
fileReader = pdf.PdfFileReader(file)

# print the number of pages in pdf file
textData = []

for pages in fileReader.pages:
    theText = pages.extractText()

    # for char in theText:
    #   theText.replace(char, "\n")

    textData.append(theText)

final_list = []

for i in textData:
    if i in stopwords.words('english'):
        textData.remove(i)
    final_list.append(i.strip('\n'))

# filtered_word_list = final_list[:] #make a copy of the word_list

# for word in final_list: # iterate over word_list
#   if word in stopwords.words('english'):
#       final_list.remove(word) # remove word from filtered_word_list if it is a stopword

# filtered_words = [word for word in final_list if word not in stop_words]

# [s.strip('\n') for s in theText]
# [s.replace('\n', '') for s in theText]


# text_data = []

# for elem in textData:
#         text_data.extend(elem.strip().split('n'))  

# for line in textData:
#     textData.append(line.strip().split('\n'))
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

import os.path

save_path = "C:\\Users\\Name\\Documents\\Data Analytics Club"

name_of_file = input("What is the name of the file: ")

completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file + ".txt")   

file1 = open(completeName, "w")

# file1.write(str(final_list))

for line in final_list:
    file1.write(line)

file1.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line

```
if i in stopwords.words('english'):
    textData.remove(i)
```

You are only removing a single occurrence of that word. If you read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) it simply removes the first occurrence of the word.

What you probably want to do instead to remove it is:

**Python 2**

```
filter(lambda x: x != i, textData)
```

**Python 3**

```
list(filter(lambda x: x != i, textData))
```

**EDIT**

So I realized quite a bit late that you are actually iterating over the list that you are removing elements from. So, you would probably not want to do that. For more information, reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating)

Instead, what you would want to do is:

```
for i in set(textData):
    if i in stopwords.words('english'):
        pass
    else
        final_list.append(i.strip('\n'))
```

**EDIT 2**

So apparently the issue comes from here and needs to be fixed to:

```
for pages in fileReader.pages:
    theText = pages.extractText()
    words = theText.splitlines()
    textData.append(theText)
```

However, for the file I tested this against, it still gave issues with spacing and merged words in the same sentence. It gave me words such as `'sameuserwithinacertaintimeinterval(typicallysettoa'` and `'bedirectionaltocapturethefactthatonestorywasclicked'`

That being said, the issue lies within the PyPDF2 class. You may wish to resort to another reader. Comment if it still doesn't help

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the txt file still looks the same as before, without any of the stopwords() removed. I have tried numerous methods, and yours looked very promising, but alas Python doesn't like me very much I guess. Could the problem be linked to the txt file writing portion? It worked with a regular print() but not in the txt. Thanks.

Comment: Give me a minute to test something. I believe that `pages.extractText()` is providing one long string instead of words. If that is the case, then you will need to use `split(" ")` to form it into words.

Comment: And don't lose hope, we have all been down this road where we feel that the programming language doesn't treat us well. And you did a pretty good job so far, so kudos :)

Comment: I edited my solution. Sadly it seems the issue is with the pypdf2 library

Comment: Aww that's a shame. I currently don't know of any other libraries or methods to read words from a pdf. Anyhow, thanks for all of the help and for the kind words of encouragement!