# Inserting an item of one list to another list

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing, addition

I want to join two lists which are in the following form:

```
a=[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[11,21,31],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]],[[41,42,43],[48,45,46],[76,86,96]]]
b=[[55,66,99],[77,88,44],[100,101,100]]
```

Such that the result is:

```
result =[[[55,1,2,3],[66,4,5,6],[99,7,8,9]],[[77,11,21,31],[88,14,15,16],[44,17,18,19]],[[100,41,42,43],[101,48,45,46],[100,76,86,96]]]
```

I tried doing this, but it does not work

```
for i in range(len(a)): 
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        a[i][j].insert(0, b[i][j])

a
```

Comment: It does not work out because position 3 onwards, you start to have a list of list of list, so you need to handle that case which you do not.

Comment: works fine now :)

Comment: you mean you got the solution?

Comment: yes, the code works now

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
a=[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[11,21,31],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]],[[41,42,43],[48,45,46],[76,86,96]]]
b=[[55,66,99],[77,88,44],[100,101,100]]
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        result = a[i][j]
        result.insert(0, b[i][j])
        print(result)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, we appreciate your input! Please edit your question according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and explain a bit your code, why it answers the question, how it works, ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest not to change an iterable you're iterating over.
You can read more at [Modifying list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating).

Secondly, I want to propose using a nested loops with `zip` functions for a solution:

```
a = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[11,21,31],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]],[[41,42,43],[48,45,46],[76,86,96]]]
b = [[55,66,99],[77,88,44],[100,101,100]]
c = []

for i, j in zip(a, b):
    for k, m in zip(i, j):
        c.append([m] + k)  # k.insert(0, m) if you want to change k in-place (not recommended)
```

The outer loop iterates over first-level nested lists in `a` and over lists in `b`. The inner loop iterates over second-level lists in `a` and over integers in `b`. The values are merged into a single `list` that will be appended to a `c`.

You can read more about `zip` function at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip.