# Removing item in list in Python3 as a for loop - weird behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
def rem_items(lst):
    for i in lst:
        print(lst)
        time.sleep(1)
        lst.remove(i)


rem_items(lst)
```

returns

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 4, 5]
```

I can understand the first two lines, but why does it remove 3 instead of 2?
And why is it stopping after removing 3, not 2,4,5?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over the list [1,2,3,4,5] and modifying its length.
Writing

```
for i in lst:
    print(lst)
    time.sleep(1)
    lst.remove(i)
```

is the same as writing

```
lst_iter = iter(lst):
for i in lst_iter:
    print(lst)
    time.sleep(1)
    lst.remove(i)
```

Internally iterator holds a pointer aka index aka position of current item in the list. The loop directive calls i=next(lst_iter) internally, until StopIteration exception is raised.

In your case calling next(lst_iter) for the 1st time returns **first** element of list [1,2,3,4,5], which is 1. Calling next(lst_iter) for the 2nd time returns **second** element of list [2,3,4,5], which is 3.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the list while iterating over it. This is generally a Bad Thing to do and can lead to unpredictable results.

See here for more info:
[Modifying list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating)