# Last element is not running in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am running a similar for loop but last element is not running , execution is exiting for loop

```py
numbers = [5,6] 
for x in numbers:
   print(x)
   numbers.remove(x)
```

Comment: Never change the list you are iterating over!

Comment: This answer explains why you cannot modify a list you are looping through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating#1637875

Answer (score 0):

It is usually not best practise to iterate the list you are looping through because things get messy:
You could simply remove the `remove` statement and it will work just fine.

If you want to empty the list you could do so out of the loop like this:
`numbers = []`

If you really need to iterate the list in the for loop though, I suggest you using a copy of your numbers list:

```
numbers = [5,6]
copied_list = numbers.copy()

for x in numbers:
    print(x)
    copied_list.remove(x)
```

Comment: *"It is usually not best practise to iterate a list in a loop"* It is actually one of the most important use-cases for a list and completely fine!

Comment: @KlausD. Sort of spelling mistake. Thanks for noticing it. Corrected it right away

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear this list you could just use `clear()`.

```
numbers = [5,6] 
numbers.clear()
```

output

```
[]
```

#Note: do not mutate or mess with the iterable you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

You are **not permitted** to remove elements from the list while iterating over it using a for loop.

Alternatively, you could use a `while` loop:

```
while numbers:
   numbers.pop(0)
   print(numbers)
```