# Insert element to for loop after a loop started

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Is it possible to add an element to the 'for' loop after the loop has started, so that the loop will include this element?

```
x = [object1, object2]

for object in x:
    if statement:
        x.append(object3)
```

or should i find a way in "while" loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637807/modifying-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably go with something like this. But be aware whatever calculations you make to obtain 'object3' have to lead to a series with tendency towards the condition (Don't get trapped in the loop ;)

```
def iteration(x):
    object3 = x[-2] + x[-1]
    if object3 < 1000:
        x.append(object3)
        iteration(x)
    else:
        return x

x = [0, 1]
iteration(x)
print(x)
```