# Trouble comparing floats in Python

Tags: python, math, precision

I know that this should be easier, but I've having issues comparing float values.

I have some very basic code that is doing a few things:

1. Any weights under 5 are added to light_pkgs.
2. Any weights over 15 are added to heavy_pkgs.
3. Any weights over 15 are removed from the original `packages` list.

```
def process_packages(package_list):
    light_pkgs = []
    heavy_pkgs = []

    light_weight = 5.00
    heavy_weight = 15.00

    for i in package_list:
        if i < light_weight:
            light_pkgs.append(i)

        elif i > heavy_weight:
            heavy_pkgs.append(i)
            packages.remove(i)

    return light_pkgs, heavy_pkgs


packages = [2.4, 3.44, 4.55, 4.9, 5.11, 5.31, 5.61, 5.99, 6.11, 7.34, 7.9, 9, 11.3, 15.1, 15.31, 15.68, 15.9, 16.7, 19.3, 21]
print(process_packages(packages))
print(packages)
```

I believe that due to precision errors my code isn't identifying several of the numbers in the 15.xx range.

Also, I'm limited to using built-in Python functions.

Expected Output:

```
([2.4, 3.44, 4.55, 4.9], [15.1, 15.31, 15.68, 15.9, 16.7, 19.3, 21])
[2.4, 3.44, 4.55, 4.9, 5.11, 5.31, 5.61, 5.99, 6.11, 7.34, 7.9, 9, 11.3]
```

Actual Output:

```
([2.4, 3.44, 4.55, 4.9], [15.1, 15.68, 16.7, 21])
[2.4, 3.44, 4.55, 4.9, 5.11, 5.31, 5.61, 5.99, 6.11, 7.34, 7.9, 9, 11.3, 15.31, 15.9, 19.3]
```

As you can see several numbers above 15 are not being added to the heavy_pkgs list, and aren't being removed from the original packages list.

Comment: Where is `packages` declared before `def process_packages(package_list):`? I think we need your full code to work this out. My guess is that because lists are passed by reference,  `packages.remove(i)` is removing items from `package_list` while iterating over it because both variables are bound to the same list instance.

Comment: I removed `packages.remove(i)` from your example and the output is what you would expect. 

See this answer for why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637875/9925060

Comment: @SimonCrowe, not sure what we mean. This is the complete code. `def process_packages(package_list):` can be declared before the actual `packages` list.  It's good practice, in my opinion, to place your functions above your main running code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're experiencing the problem from [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207406/364696) with extra steps.

`packages` in global scope is the same thing as `package_list` in the function's scope (they're both aliases to the same `list`). When you `remove` from it while iterating over it, you skip iterating over the element that immediately follows the removed element (because it moves a slot down, and the iterator advances past that slot on the next loop).

Build a new `list` with the light and medium weights, and replace the contents of `package_list` *after* the loop completes, and things should work (and work more efficiently, as *each* call to `remove` is `O(n)`, so the overall work is `O(n²)`, while a two pass build-and-replace is `O(n)`).

```
def process_packages(package_list):
    light_pkgs = []
    not_heavy_pkgs = []  # Temporary list to hold stuff that should remain in package_list
    heavy_pkgs = []

    light_weight = 5.00
    heavy_weight = 15.00

    for i in package_list:
        if i < light_weight:
            light_pkgs.append(i)
            not_heavy_pkgs.append(i)  # Looks like light things are supposed to stay in too
        elif i > heavy_weight:
            heavy_pkgs.append(i)
        else:
            not_heavy_pkgs.append(i)  # It's not heavy, so retain it 

    package_list[:] = not_heavy_pkgs  # Assigning to complete slice replaces contents of
                                   # package_list in place, affecting caller's version of list
                                   # as your original code tried to do

    return light_pkgs, heavy_pkgs
```

That code does get a bit unwieldy. While it would involve a couple more passes over the input, it would be much more succinct to rely on a handful of list comprehensions here:

```
def process_packages(package_list):
    heavy_weight = 15.0
    # Get heavy packages
    heavy_pkgs = [pkg for pkg in package_list if pkg > heavy_weight]
    # Remove heavy packages from source
    package_list[:] = [pkg for pkg in package_list if pkg <= heavy_weight]

    # One more pass to get light packages and we're done
    # This pass is somewhat cheaper, because heavy items were already removed
    return [pkg for pkg in package_list if pkg < 5.0], heavy_pkgs
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, thank you. I knew it was something that I was missing in regards to how Python was handling the removal, but couldn't understand exactly why items in the loop were being skipped.

Personally, I would have used list comprehensions, but I'm helping a friend out with understanding lists and loops as a basic level, and she's a math major.

Answer (score -1):

When you remove an item from a for loop, which item will become the next index?
For eg., if you remove 3rd item(i.e idx 3), after the removal, the 4th item will become the third item.(Just like if someone goes out from a queue, the person next to him will come to his position). Even after the removal, the loop goes on in its ascending order. So after the index 3, the next index is 4. But since the previous index-4 has become index-3 now, the present index-4 is the previous index-5. So, Even if the previous index-4 is over 15, that is left unremoved.

So instead of for loop, use a while loop. And if the item is removed, reduce the index value by one and also reduce the length of the package_list by one. That's it.

```
def process_packages(package_list):
    light_pkgs = []
    heavy_pkgs = []
    L = len(package_list)
    i = 0

    light_weight = 5.00
    heavy_weight = 15.00

    while i<L:
        x = package_list[i]
        if x < light_weight:
            light_pkgs.append(x)
        elif x > heavy_weight:
            heavy_pkgs.append(x)
            packages.remove(x)
            i = i-1
            L = L-1
        i += 1
        
    return light_pkgs, heavy_pkgs
#Output: 
([2.4, 3.44, 4.55, 4.9], [15.1, 15.31, 15.68, 15.9, 16.7, 19.3, 21])
[2.4, 3.44, 4.55, 4.9, 5.11, 5.31, 5.61, 5.99, 6.11, 7.34, 7.9, 9, 11.3]
```