# How do I handle a logical test not evaluating to True

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, big-o

I wrote a for loop in Python which I submitted in my discussion post in a CS class. It involves extracting the even elements from a list and appending them into another list. I wrote the following code which I think should work well.

```py
data = [9,4,5,17,12,14,1,0,3,10,9]
even = []
for item in data:
    if (item % 2) == 0:
        data.remove(item)
        even.append(item)
    else:
        pass
```

To my surprise, I got the following result after running the code.

```
muyiwa@mobadara-pc:~/Documents/projects/DSA-2/Unit2$ python fixed_.code.py 
The even elements are: [4, 12, 0, 10]
The odd elements are: [9, 5, 17, 14, 1, 3, 9]
```

I believe the element"14" which is an even number should not be in the odd list anymore since `14 % 2 == 0` evaluates to `True`

Please, help me out.

Comment: You are modifying the list you are looping in, this is a bad idea and also produces somehow hard to debug and "unexpected" results.

Comment: never modify what you are iterating on to be safe from such behaviors

Comment: Then, I need to create new lists `even = []` and `odd = []` and append appropriately. Thank you. I want to know why 14 is being skipped in the test also.

Comment: @MuyiwaJ.Obadara please see the answer from Alex for the explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637875/13086128

Comment: `14` is being skipped because the loop goes over each item sequentially and it knows where it's at by index. If you remove the current item you shift the index of all the later elements by `-1`, so in the iteration that hits index `5` instead of finding `14` it finds some other number instead. This is illustrated further in the linked duplicate. It's also a pretty common programming "gotcha" that removing items from the thing you are iterating can cause issues.

Answer (score 2):

**Why you should not modify a list while you are iterating over it :**

As the previous comments said, you are modifying the list while iterating over it.
Use data.copy() to iterate over a copy of the list.

Here is what happens with your approach :

1. The code looks at what is at index 0
2. The value at index 0 is odd : do nothing.
3. Look at what is at index 1.
4. The value is even. Remove the value. Append the value in the "even" list. (`[9(index 0), 4(index 1), 5(index 2), 17(index 3)]` becomes `[9(index 0), 5(index 1), 17(index 2)]`)
5. Look at what is at index 2 : the value 17. Why ? Because you removed a value from the list. So the value 17 that was previously at index 3 is now at index 2.

When you iterate over a copy of the list, you can evaluate the values inside the copy while removing anything you want from the original list. You won't break your index.

```py
data = [9,4,5,17,12,14,1,0,3,10,9]
even = []
for item in data.copy():
    if (item % 2) == 0:
        data.remove(item)
        even.append(item)
    else:
        pass

print(data)  # [9, 5, 17, 1, 3, 9]
print(even)  # [4, 12, 14, 0, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are removing items while you are in the loop, and thus skipping number 14.

You cloud create a new list called odd:

```py
data = [9,4,5,17,12,14,1,0,3,10,9]
even = []
odd = []
for item in data:
    if (item % 2) == 0:
        even.append(item)
    else:
        odd.append(item)
    
print(odd)
print(even)
```