# Count Amount of Values in a List

Tags: python, list, count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the size of a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712227/get-the-size-of-a-list-in-python)

I need to be able to count how many values there are in total there are in a list.
eg. [1,5,9,4,6], there are 5 values.
I have tried using the

list.count() function, but that returns how many of one value there is.

Is there any way to calculate how many values there are in the list?

Thanks

(The outcome/amount also needs to be stored in a variable.)

Comment: Note that lists keep track of their length internally; `len(somelist)` is thus a fast operation as it simply looks up a variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712227/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
len(your_list)
```

Please read your favorite Python tutorial.