# how to find how many strings when .split is used

Tags: python, split

In python what code can I use in an if statement to check a string, after I did the .split code on it to see if there was only one string created?

Comment: If you've read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) on string splitting in Python, and on [lists](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/lists.html) and existing answers on how to find the [length of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712227/get-the-size-of-a-list-in-python), and are still puzzled, you could ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.split()` returns a list, you can call the function `len()` on that list to get how many items `.split()' returns:

```
>>> s = 'one two three'
>>> s.split()
['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> lst = s.split()
>>> len(lst)
3
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this

```
if len(myString.split()) == 1:
   ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def main():
    str = "This is a string that contains words."
    words = str.split()
    word_count = len(words)
    print word_count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Fiddle: http://ideone.com/oqpV2h