# Mongodb, osm street maps, unique users

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I imported a json file into my database, and the db itself works.

If use

```
print db.points.find_one()
```

my output looks like :

```
{u'id': u'342902', u'_id': ObjectId('555af76a029d3b1b0ff9a4be'), u'type': u'node', u'pos': [48.9979746, 8.3719741], u'created': {u'changeset': u'7105928', u'version': u'4', u'uid': u'163673', u'timestamp': u'2011-01-27T18:05:54Z', u'user': u'Free_Jan'}}
```

which is exactly what I want it to be. But if I want to get the number of distinct users:

```
print db.points.distinct({"created.user"}).length
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: key must be an instance of basestring
```

which suggests that what I was searching for is not there (it clearly is as shown above). What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your distinct clause - it should be `.distinct("created.user")` instead of `.distinct({"created.user"})`.

See [the MongoDB documentation for distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/).

**Edit:** To return the length, therefore, something like:

```
print len(db.points.distinct("created.user"));
```

... or:

```
print db.points.distinct("created.user").__len__();
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27137427/789529) for getting the size of a list in Python.

Caveat: I'm no Python expert so the length bit might not be perfect...

Comment: Hhmm i changed it , according to your suggestion ( thank you by the way) , now i get a different error :  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'length'

Comment: I'm no expert at Python but I believe you need something like __len__() rather than .length. Editing to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem.

`print len(db.points.distinct("created.user"))` works.

However, 
`print db.points.distinct("created.user").__len__();`
does not.

The reason for the error is the braces:

`db.points.distinct({"created.user"})`

should read

`db.points.distinct("created.user")`
Also, '.length' is a mongo bash method. In pymongo, you use 'len()'. That is:

`db.points.distinct({"created.user"}).length`
should read

`print len(db.points.distinct("created.user"))`
unless you are using mongo bash/shell.