# IndexError: list index out of range in for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, indexing

I write a code in python but I faced this error :

```
if a1[i] == a1[i+1] == a1[i+2]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I write an if condition that if my list length is less than 3, break the for, but it does not work.

**My Code :**

```
numb = int(input())
a1 = []
a2 = []
a = 0
a1 = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
for i in range(0, numb):
    a2.append("empty")


for i in range(0, len(a1)-2):
    if len(a1) < 3:
        break
    else:
        if a1[i] == a1[i+1] == a1[i+2]:
            a = a + 1
            a2[i] = a
            a2[i+1] = a
            a2[i+2] = a
            a1.remove(a1[i+2])
            a1.remove(a1[i+1])
            a1.remove(a1[i])
```

Why do I face this error?
Is it because my if-condition does not work?

**In Addition, I'm sorry for writing mistakes in my question.**

Comment: *[...] if my list length is less than 3* then just use `len()` function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712227/how-to-get-the-number-of-elements-in-a-list-in-python

Comment: i try this, but i faced same error

Comment: The reason that you're getting `IndexError` is because you're trying to use indexes that are not available in your list. You should find out where are you doing such thing and correct it.

Comment: `range(0, len(a1)-2)` is only evaluated once, but you change `len` of the list with `remove`. [How does a for loop evaluate its argument](//stackoverflow.com/a/35439647)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank You, my Problem is solve.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop goes from `0` to `len(a1)-2`, while you should only go to `len(a1)-3`:

When you are working with `i`, let `i` go from `0` to `len(a1)-1`.
When you are working with `i` and `i+1`, let `i` go from `0` to `len(a1)-2`.
When you are working with `i`, `i+1` and `i+2` let `i` go from `0` to `len(a1)-3`.