# Can I set a variable to nothing?

Tags: python

The question kind of explains it. I was thinking it would be something like:

```
x = None
if sUserInt == x:
    #do stuff here
```

I'm using it to check if a user has just pushed enter and put nothing in at all.
Thanks!

Comment: Your input won't be nothing; it'll be an empty string. That may seem like nothing, but they're as different as `1` and `'1'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't have to define a new variable only to compare its value. So instead of

```
x = None
if sUserInt == x:
    #do stuff here
```

You could write

```
if sUserInt == None:
    #do stuff here
```

However, in case of None, you can use the [implicit checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459513/why-implicitly-check-for-emptiness-in-python) of a variable being None:

```
if not sUserInt:
    #do stuff here
```

And finally, all these won't help you anyway, because simply pushing an enter on raw_input() won't give you None, but an empty string ('').

So use:

```
if sUserInt == '':
        #do stuff here
```

or check the length of input

```
if len(sUserInt) == 0:
        #do stuff here
```

or use the implicit *string* checking again:

```
if not sUserInt:
        #do stuff here
```

All the last three solutions mean basically the same thing.

Comment: You used the implicit false for `None`, but not `''`?

Answer (score 2):

Rather Use :

```
if not sUserInt:
    #do something here
```

Example usage:

```
sUserInt = raw_input()
if not sUserInt:
    print "Nothing Entered"
```

If nothing was entered it would print `Nothing Entered`

Comment: Note that sUserInt is an empty string ('') and not None in this case. However, implicit checking of emptyness still works for strings.