# What's the recommended way to return a boolean for a collection being non-empty in python?

Tags: python, collections

I came across the question [Python: What is the best way to check if a list is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/python-what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty) on SO.

Now if I wanted to return a `True` (`False`) depending on whether a collection `coll` is non-empty (empty) from a function, what's the recommended way of doing this ? `return not not coll` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use

```
return bool(coll)
```