# Iterating over a stack (reverse list), is there an isempty() method?

Tags: python, stack, iteration

What's the best way to iterate over a stack in Python?

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
while (len(a) > 0)
  print a.pop()

# prints 4, 3, 2, 1 in sequence
```

I couldn't find an `isempty` method, and checking the length each time seems wrong somehow.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Print in reverse?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The usual convention for containers is that they are True while not empty and False when empty, so you can just do:

```
while a:
    print a.pop()
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the list as a boolean condition which evaluates to `False` only if the list is empty:

```
>>> while a:
...     print a.pop()
... 
4
3
2
1
```

Not only is this more concise, it is also more efficient (1.49ms vs 1.9ms for a list of 10,000) since it only has to check if there is a first element:

```
$ python -mtimeit -c 'a=range(10000)
while len(a):
  a.pop()'
10000 loops, best of 3: 1.9 msec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -c 'a=range(10000)
while a:     
  a.pop()'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 msec per loop
```

You can also use [`reversed()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed) to get a reverse iterator:

```
>>> for n in reversed(a):
...     print n
... 
4
3
2
1
```

Or in one line:

```
print '\n'.join(map(str, reversed(a)))
```

Note that this will *not* remove the elements from the list. If necessary, you can achieve that with `del a[:]`.

Answer (score 2):

[Python: What is the best way to check if a list is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/python-what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty)

[Stack (Python)](http://en.literateprograms.org/Stack_%28Python%29)