# Calculating arithmetic mean (one type of average) in Python

Tags: python, list, mean

Is there a built-in or standard library method in Python to calculate the arithmetic mean (one type of average) of a list of numbers?

Comment: Average is ambiguous - mode and median are also commonly-used averages

Comment: Mode and median are other measures of central tendency.  They are not averages.  The mode is the most common value seen in a data set and is not necessarily unique.  The median is the value that represents the center of the data points. As the question implies, there are a few different types of averages, but all are different from median and mode calculations.  http://www.purplemath.com/modules/meanmode.htm

Comment: @Jarom That link disagrees with you: 'Mean, median, and mode are three kinds of "averages"'

Answer (score 288, accepted):

I am not aware of anything in the standard library. However, you could use something like:

```
def mean(numbers):
    return float(sum(numbers)) / max(len(numbers), 1)

>>> mean([1,2,3,4])
2.5
>>> mean([])
0.0
```

In numpy, there's [`numpy.mean()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html).

Comment: A common thing is to consider that the average of `[]` is `0`, which can be done by `float(sum(l))/max(len(l),1)`.

Comment: PEP 8 [says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid) that `l` is a bad variable name because it looks so much like `1`.  Also, I would use `if l` rather than `if len(l) > 0`.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513)

Comment: Why have you called `max`?

Comment: See the question above: To avoid division by zero ( for [] )

Comment: In Python 3, you don't need the call to `float`. Also, in my opinion, it makes sense to raise a `ZeroDivisionError` for an empty list, instead of returning 0. With those changes, the code would be: `return sum(numbers) / len(numbers)`.

Comment: In python 3, there is a mean function in the "statistics" package: https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean.

Comment: Empty lists have no mean. Please don't pretend they do.

Answer (score 196):

NumPy has a [`numpy.mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) which is an arithmetic mean. Usage is as simple as this:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = [1, 2, 4]
>>> numpy.mean(a)
2.3333333333333335
```

Comment: numpy is a nightmare to install in a virtualenv. You should really consider not using this lib

Comment: If there is a system-wide numpy installation, you can probably use its mean.

Comment: @vcarel: "numpy is a nightmare to install in a virtualenv".

I'm not sure why you say this.  It used to be the case, but for the last year or more it's been very easy.

Comment: I must second this comment.  I'm currently using numpy in a virtualenv in OSX, and there is absolutely no problem (currently using CPython 3.5).

Comment: With continuous integration systems like Travis CI, installing numpy takes several extra minutes. If quick and light build is valuable to you, and you need only the mean, consider.

Comment: @AkseliPalén [virtual environments on Travis CI can use a numpy installed via apt-get using the system site packages](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2012/11/23/use-apt-get-to-install-python-dependencies-for-travis-ci/). This may be quick enough to use even if one only needs a mean.

Comment: Python 2.7, via macports, on OSX Sierra.  numpy (1.12.1), virtualenv 15.1.0.  No problemo whatsoever on virtualenv.

Comment: `pip install numpy`. Done!

Comment: This comments section is pretty outdated. numpy is very standard now!

Answer (score 191):

Use [`statistics.mean`](http://docs.python.org/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean):

```
import statistics
print(statistics.mean([1,2,4])) # 2.3333333333333335
```

It's available since Python 3.4. For 3.1-3.3 users, an old version of the module is available on PyPI under the name [`stats`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stats/0.1.2a). Just change `statistics` to `stats`.

Comment: Note that this is extremely slow when compared to the other solutions. Compare `timeit("numpy.mean(vec))`, `timeit("sum(vec)/len(vec)")` and `timeit("statistics.mean(vec)")` - the latter is slower than the others by a huge factor (>100 in some cases on my PC). This appears to be due to a particularly precise implementation of the `sum` operator in `statistics`, see [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0450/) and [Code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/statistics.py). Not sure about the reason for the large performance difference between `statistics._sum` and `numpy.sum`, though.

Comment: @jhin this is because the `statistics.mean` tries to be *correct*. It calculates correctly the mean of `[1e50, 1, -1e50] * 1000`.

Comment: `statistics.mean` will also accept a generator expression of values, which all solutions that use `len()` for the divisor will choke on.

Comment: Since python 3.8, there is a faster `statistics.fmean` function

Answer (score 55):

You don't even need numpy or scipy...

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> print(sum(a) / len(a))
3
```

Comment: then mean([2,3]) would give 2. be careful with floats. Better use float(sum(l))/len(l). Better still, be careful to check if the list is empty.

Comment: @jesusiniesta except in python3, where division does what it is intended to do : divide

Comment: And in Python 2.2+ if you `from __future__ import division` at the top of your program

Comment: What about big numbers and overflow?

Comment: What about `a = list()`? The proposed code results in `ZeroDivisionError`.

Comment: @Ioannis That's arguably working as expected. All the other answers raise an error or a warning on an empty sequence.

Answer (score 8):

Use scipy:

```
import scipy;
a=[1,2,4];
print(scipy.mean(a));
```

Comment: [scipy.stats.mean is deprecated; please update your code to use numpy.mean.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.8.x/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mean.html)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of casting to float you can do following

```
def mean(nums):
    return sum(nums, 0.0) / len(nums)
```

or using lambda

```
mean = lambda nums: sum(nums, 0.0) / len(nums)
```

UPDATES: 2019-12-15

Python 3.8 added function [fmean](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.fmean) to [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#module-statistics) module. Which is faster and always returns float.

> Convert data to floats and compute the arithmetic mean.
>
> This runs faster than the mean() function and it always returns a
>   float. The data may be a sequence or iterable. If the input dataset is
>   empty, raises a StatisticsError.
>
> fmean([3.5, 4.0, 5.25])
>
> 4.25
>
> New in version 3.8.

Answer (score 3):

```
from statistics import mean
avarage=mean(your_list)
```

for example

```
from statistics import mean

my_list=[5,2,3,2]
avarage=mean(my_list)
print(avarage)
```

and result is

```
3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using python >= 3.8, you can use the [`fmean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.fmean) function introduced in the `statistics` module which is part of the standard library:

```py
>>> from statistics import fmean
>>> fmean([0, 1, 2, 3])
1.5
```

It's faster than the `statistics.mean` function, but it converts its data points to `float` beforehand, so it can be less accurate in some specific cases.

You can see its implementation [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/statistics.py#L321)

Answer (score 1):

```
def list_mean(nums):
    sumof = 0
    num_of = len(nums)
    mean = 0
    for i in nums:
        sumof += i
    mean = sumof / num_of
    return float(mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def avg(l):
    """uses floating-point division."""
    return sum(l) / float(len(l))
```

#### Examples:

```
l1 = [3,5,14,2,5,36,4,3]
l2 = [0,0,0]

print(avg(l1)) # 9.0
print(avg(l2)) # 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper answer to your question is to use `statistics.mean`. But for fun, here is a version of mean that does not use the `len()` function, so it (like `statistics.mean`) can be used on generators, which do not support `len()`:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import truediv
def ave(seq):
    return truediv(*reduce(lambda a, b: (a[0] + b[1], b[0]), 
                           enumerate(seq, start=1), 
                           (0, 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I always supposed `avg` is omitted from the builtins/stdlib because it is as simple as

```
sum(L)/len(L) # L is some list
```

and any caveats would be *addressed in caller code for local usage already*.

Notable caveats:

1. non-float result: in python2, 9/4 is 2. to resolve, use `float(sum(L))/len(L)` or `from __future__ import division`
2. division by zero: the list may be empty. to resolve:

   ```
   if not L:
       raise WhateverYouWantError("foo")
   avg = float(sum(L))/len(L)
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Others already posted very good answers, but some people might still be looking for a classic way to find Mean(avg), so here I post this (code tested in Python 3.6):

```
def meanmanual(listt):

mean = 0
lsum = 0
lenoflist = len(listt)

for i in listt:
    lsum += i

mean = lsum / lenoflist
return float(mean)

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
meanmanual(a)

Answer: 3.5
```