# Finding the average of a list

Tags: python, list, average, mean, reduce

How do I find the arithmetic mean of a list in Python? For example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]  ⟶  2.5
```

Comment: `sum(L) / float(len(L))`. handle empty lists in caller code like `if not L: ...`

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716331/

Comment: @mitch: it's not a matter of whether you can afford installing numpy. numpy is a whole word in itself. It's whether you actually need numpy. Installing numpy, a 16mb C extension, for mean calculating would be, well, very impractical, for someone not using it for other things.

Comment: instead of installing the whole numpy package for just avg/mean if using python 3 we can get this thing done using statistic module
just by "from statistic import mean"

or if on python 2.7 or less, the statistic module can be downloaded from src:  https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/statistics.py

doc: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/statistics.html

   and directly used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating arithmetic mean (average) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716331/calculating-arithmetic-mean-average-in-python)

Comment: For anybody wandering, the reason a lot of upvoted answers in this post use the variable name `xs` is that it's a Haskell convention and this being a mathematical question might inspire the homage to that language.

Answer (score 845, accepted):

For Python 3.8+, use [`statistics.fmean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.fmean) for numerical stability with floats. (Fast.)

For Python 3.4+, use [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) for numerical stability with floats. (Slower.)

```
xs = [15, 18, 2, 36, 12, 78, 5, 6, 9]

import statistics
statistics.mean(xs)  # = 20.11111111111111
```

For older versions of Python 3, use

```
sum(xs) / len(xs)
```

For Python 2, convert `len` to a float to get float division:

```
sum(xs) / float(len(xs))
```

Comment: as i said, i'm new to this, i was thinking i'd have to make it with a loop or something to count the amount of numbers in it, i didn't realise i could just use the length. this is the first thing i've done with python..

Comment: what if the sum is a massive number that wont fit in int/float ?

Comment: @FooBarUser then you should calc k = 1.0/len(l), and then reduce: reduce(lambda x, y: x + y * k, l)

Comment: downvoted because I cannot see why reduce and lambda should be on the top of a question about avarage calculation

Comment: He should really be using sum though, as guido says to try really hard to avoid reduce

Comment: with given list of floats, given hardware and py2.7.x,  `lambda...` --> 2.59us, `numpy.mean(l)` --> 27.5us, `sum(l)/len(;)` --> 650ns

Comment: In recent Python 3, `/` returns a `float` regardless. You can use `from__future__ import division` to ensure the same behavior in Python 2.2 and up (so basically any version that's suitable for production today).

Comment: BTW `math.fsum(l) / len(l)` is faster then `fmean`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62402574/8953378

Answer (score 595):

```
xs = [15, 18, 2, 36, 12, 78, 5, 6, 9]
sum(xs) / len(xs)
```

Comment: As a C++ programmer, that is neat as hell and float is not ugly at all!

Comment: If you want to reduce some numbers after decimal point. This might come in handy: ```float('%.2f' % float(sum(l) / len(l)))```

Comment: @Steinfeld I don't think conversion to string is the best way to go here. You can achieve the same in a cleaner way with `round(result, 2)`.

Answer (score 322):

Use [`numpy.mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html):

```
xs = [15, 18, 2, 36, 12, 78, 5, 6, 9]

import numpy as np
print(np.mean(xs))
```

Comment: That's strange.  I would have assumed this would be much more efficient, but it appears to take 8 times as long on a random list of floats than simply `sum(l)/len(l)`

Comment: Oh, but `np.array(l).mean()` is *much* faster.

Comment: @L.AmberO'Hearn, I just timed it and `np.mean(l)` and `np.array(l).mean` are about the same speed, and `sum(l)/len(l)` is about twice as fast. I used `l = list(np.random.rand(1000))`, for course both `numpy` methods become much faster if `l` is `numpy.array`.

Comment: well, unless that's the sole reason for installing numpy. installing a 16mb C package of whatever fame for mean calculation looks very strange on this scale.

Comment: Also it's better to use `np.nanmean(l)` in order to avoid issues with **NAN** and **zero** divisions

Answer (score 243):

For [Python 3.4+](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.4.html#statistics), use [`mean()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) from the new [`statistics`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/statistics.html#module-statistics) module to calculate the average:

```
from statistics import mean
xs = [15, 18, 2, 36, 12, 78, 5, 6, 9]
mean(xs)
```

Comment: This is the most elegant answer because it employs a standard library module which is available since python 3.4.

Comment: And it is numerically stabler

Comment: And it produces a nicer error if you accidentally pass in an empty list `statistics.StatisticsError: mean requires at least one data point` instead of a more cryptic `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero` for the `sum(x) / len(x)` solution.

Answer (score 51):

Why would you use `reduce()` for this when Python has a perfectly cromulent `sum()` function?

```
print sum(l) / float(len(l))
```

(The `float()` is necessary in Python 2 to force Python to do a floating-point division.)

Comment: For those of us new to the word ['cromulent'](http://nl.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cromulent)

Comment: `float()` is not necessary on Python 3.

Answer (score 39):

There is a statistics library if you are using python >= 3.4

https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html

You may use it's mean method like this. Let's say you have a list of numbers of which you want to find mean:-

```
list = [11, 13, 12, 15, 17]
import statistics as s
s.mean(list)
```

It has other methods too like stdev, variance, mode, harmonic mean, median etc which are too useful.

Answer (score 19):

Instead of casting to float, you can add 0.0 to the sum:

```
def avg(l):
    return sum(l, 0.0) / len(l)
```

Answer (score 18):

EDIT:

I added two other ways to get the average of a list (which are relevant only for Python 3.8+). Here is the comparison that I made:

```
import timeit
import statistics
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd
import math

LIST_RANGE = 10
NUMBERS_OF_TIMES_TO_TEST = 10000

l = list(range(LIST_RANGE))

def mean1():
    return statistics.mean(l)


def mean2():
    return sum(l) / len(l)


def mean3():
    return np.mean(l)


def mean4():
    return np.array(l).mean()


def mean5():
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y / float(len(l)), l, 0)

def mean6():
    return pd.Series(l).mean()


def mean7():
    return statistics.fmean(l)


def mean8():
    return math.fsum(l) / len(l)


for func in [mean1, mean2, mean3, mean4, mean5, mean6, mean7, mean8 ]:
    print(f"{func.__name__} took: ",  timeit.timeit(stmt=func, number=NUMBERS_OF_TIMES_TO_TEST))
```

These are the results I got:

```
mean1 took:  0.09751558300000002
mean2 took:  0.005496791999999973
mean3 took:  0.07754683299999998
mean4 took:  0.055743208000000044
mean5 took:  0.018134082999999968
mean6 took:  0.6663848750000001
mean7 took:  0.004305374999999945
mean8 took:  0.003203333000000086
```

Interesting! looks like `math.fsum(l) / len(l)` is the fastest way, then `statistics.fmean(l)`, and only then `sum(l) / len(l)`. Nice!

Thank you @Asclepius for showing me these two other ways!

---

OLD ANSWER:

In terms of efficiency and speed, these are the results that I got testing the other answers:

```
# test mean caculation

import timeit
import statistics
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd

LIST_RANGE = 10
NUMBERS_OF_TIMES_TO_TEST = 10000

l = list(range(LIST_RANGE))

def mean1():
    return statistics.mean(l)


def mean2():
    return sum(l) / len(l)


def mean3():
    return np.mean(l)


def mean4():
    return np.array(l).mean()


def mean5():
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y / float(len(l)), l, 0)

def mean6():
    return pd.Series(l).mean()



for func in [mean1, mean2, mean3, mean4, mean5, mean6]:
    print(f"{func.__name__} took: ",  timeit.timeit(stmt=func, number=NUMBERS_OF_TIMES_TO_TEST))
```

and the results:

```
mean1 took:  0.17030245899968577
mean2 took:  0.002183011999932205
mean3 took:  0.09744236000005913
mean4 took:  0.07070840100004716
mean5 took:  0.022754742999950395
mean6 took:  1.6689282460001778
```

so clearly the winner is:
`sum(l) / len(l)`

Comment: I tried these timings with a list of length 100000000: mean2 < 1s; mean3,4 ~ 8s;  mean5,6 ~ 27s; mean1 ~1minute. I find this surprising, would have expected numpy to be best with a large list, but there you go! Seems there's a problem with the statistics package!! (this was python 3.8 on a mac laptop, no BLAS as far as I know).

Comment: Incidentally, if I convert l into an `np.array` first, `np.mean` takes ~.16s, so about 6x faster than `sum(l)/len(l)`. Conclusion: if you're doing lots of calculations, best do everything in numpy.

Comment: @drevicko see `mean4`, this is what I do there... I guess that it its already a np.array then it make sense to use `np.mean`, but in case you have a list then you should use `sum(l) / len(l)`

Comment: exactly! It also depends on what you'll be doing with it later. Im my work I'm typically doing a series of calculations, so it makes sense to convert to numpy at the start and leverage numpy's fast underlying libraries.

Comment: @AlonGouldman Great. I urge showing each speed in 1/1000 of a second (as an integer), otherwise the number is hard to read. For example, 170, 2, 97, etc. This should make it so much more easily readable. Please let me know if this is done, and I will check.

Answer (score 11):

`sum(l) / float(len(l))` is the right answer, but just for completeness you can compute an average with a single reduce:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y / float(len(l)), l, 0)
20.111111111111114
```

Note that this can result in a slight rounding error:

```
>>> sum(l) / float(len(l))
20.111111111111111
```

Comment: I get that this is just for fun but returning 0 for an empty list may not be the best thing to do

Comment: @JohanLundberg - You could replace the 0 with False as the last argument to `reduce()` which would give you False for an empty list, otherwise the average as before.

Comment: @AndrewClark why do you force `float`on `len`?

Answer (score 11):

I tried using the options above but didn't work.
Try this:

```py
from statistics import mean

n = [11, 13, 15, 17, 19]

print(n)
print(mean(n))
```

worked on python 3.5

Answer (score 7):

Or use `pandas`'s `Series.mean` method:

```
pd.Series(sequence).mean()
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> l = [15, 18, 2, 36, 12, 78, 5, 6, 9]
>>> pd.Series(l).mean()
20.11111111111111
>>>
```

From the docs:

> `Series.mean(axis=None, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=None, **kwargs)`¶

And here is the docs for this:

> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html

And the whole documentation:

> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Comment: This isn't a pandas question, so it seems excessive to import such a heavy library for a simple operation like finding the mean.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar question to solve in a Udacity´s problems. Instead of a built-in function i coded:

```
def list_mean(n):

    summing = float(sum(n))
    count = float(len(n))
    if n == []:
        return False
    return float(summing/count)
```

Much more longer than usual but for a beginner its quite challenging.

Comment: Good. Every other answer didn't notice the empty list hazard!

Comment: Returning `False` (equivalent to the integer `0`) is just about the worst possible way to handle this error. Better to catch the `ZeroDivisionError` and raise something better (perhaps `ValueError`).

Comment: @kindall how is a `ValueError` any better than a `ZeroDivisionError`? The latter is more specific, plus it seems a bit unnecessary to catch an arithmetic error only to re-throw a different one.

Comment: Because `ZeroDivisionError` is only useful if you know how the calculation is being done (i.e., that a division by the length of the list is involved). If you don't know that, it doesn't tell you what the problem is with the value you passed in. Whereas your new exception can include that more specific information.

Answer (score 5):

as a beginner, I just coded this:

```
L = [15, 18, 2, 36, 12, 78, 5, 6, 9]

total = 0

def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    total = float(total)
    return total / len(numbers)

print average(L)
```

Comment: Bravo: IMHO, `sum(l)/len(l)` is by far the most elegant answer (no need to make type conversions in Python 3).

Comment: There is no need to store the values in variables or use global variables.

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to get more than just the mean (aka average) you might check out scipy stats:

```
from scipy import stats
l = [15, 18, 2, 36, 12, 78, 5, 6, 9]
print(stats.describe(l))

# DescribeResult(nobs=9, minmax=(2, 78), mean=20.11111111111111, 
# variance=572.3611111111111, skewness=1.7791785448425341, 
# kurtosis=1.9422716419666397)
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to use `reduce` for taking a running average, you'll need to track the total but also the total number of elements seen so far.  since that's not a trivial element in the list, you'll also have to pass `reduce` an extra argument to fold into.

```
>>> l = [15, 18, 2, 36, 12, 78, 5, 6, 9]
>>> running_average = reduce(lambda aggr, elem: (aggr[0] + elem, aggr[1]+1), l, (0.0,0))
>>> running_average[0]
(181.0, 9)
>>> running_average[0]/running_average[1]
20.111111111111111
```

Comment: interesting but that's not what he asked for.

Answer (score 4):

Both can give you close to similar values on an integer or at least 10 decimal values. But if you are really considering long floating values both can be different. Approach can vary on what you want to achieve.

```
>>> l = [15, 18, 2, 36, 12, 78, 5, 6, 9]
>>> print reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l) / len(l)
20
>>> sum(l)/len(l)
20
```

Floating values

```
>>> print reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l) / float(len(l))
20.1111111111
>>> print sum(l)/float(len(l))
20.1111111111
```

@Andrew Clark was correct on his statement.

Answer (score 4):

suppose that

```
x = [
    [-5.01,-5.43,1.08,0.86,-2.67,4.94,-2.51,-2.25,5.56,1.03],
    [-8.12,-3.48,-5.52,-3.78,0.63,3.29,2.09,-2.13,2.86,-3.33],
    [-3.68,-3.54,1.66,-4.11,7.39,2.08,-2.59,-6.94,-2.26,4.33]
]
```

you can notice that `x` has dimension 3*10 if you need to get the `mean` to each row you can type this

```
theMean = np.mean(x1,axis=1)
```

don't forget to `import numpy as np`

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [15, 18, 2, 36, 12, 78, 5, 6, 9]

l = map(float,l)
print '%.2f' %(sum(l)/len(l))
```

Comment: Inefficient. It converts all elements to float before adding them. It's faster to convert just the length.

Answer (score 2):

Find the average in list
By using the following **PYTHON** code:

```
l = [15, 18, 2, 36, 12, 78, 5, 6, 9]
print(sum(l)//len(l))
```

try this it easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
print reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l)/(len(l)*1.0)
```

or like posted previously

```
sum(l)/(len(l)*1.0)
```

The 1.0 is to make sure you get a floating point division

Answer (score 0):

Combining a couple of the above answers, I've come up with the following which works with reduce and doesn't assume you have `L` available inside the reducing function:

```
from operator import truediv

L = [15, 18, 2, 36, 12, 78, 5, 6, 9]

def sum_and_count(x, y):
    try:
        return (x[0] + y, x[1] + 1)
    except TypeError:
        return (x + y, 2)

truediv(*reduce(sum_and_count, L))

# prints 
20.11111111111111
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add just another approach

```
import itertools,operator
list(itertools.accumulate(l,operator.add)).pop(-1) / len(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function for averages, usage:

```
average(21,343,2983) # You can pass as many arguments as you want.
```

Here is the code:

```
def average(*args):
    total = 0
    for num in args:
        total+=num
    return total/len(args)
```

`*args` allows for any number of answers.

Comment: The usage of this is: `average(3,5,123)`, but you can input other numbers. And keep in mind that it returns a value, and doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is a avemedi-lib

```
pip install avemedi_lib
```

Than include to your script

```
from avemedi_lib.functions import average, get_median, get_median_custom


test_even_array = [12, 32, 23, 43, 14, 44, 123, 15]
test_odd_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# Getting average value of list items
print(average(test_even_array))  # 38.25

# Getting median value for ordered or unordered numbers list
print(get_median(test_even_array))  # 27.5
print(get_median(test_odd_array))  # 27.5

# You can use your own sorted and your count functions
a = sorted(test_even_array)
n = len(a)

print(get_median_custom(a, n))  # 27.5
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `statistics.mean()`, `statistics.fmean()` works for a list of objects with different numeric types. For example:

```py
from decimal import Decimal
import statistics

data = [1, 4.5, Decimal('3.5')]
statistics.mean(data)     # TypeError
statistics.fmean(data)    # OK
```

This is because under the hood, `mean()` uses `statistics._sum()` which returns a data type to convert the mean into (and Decimal is not on Python's number hierarchy), while `fmean()` uses `math.fsum()` which just adds the numbers up (which is also much faster than built-in `sum()` function).

One consequence of this is that `fmean()` always returns a float (because averaging involves division) while `mean()` could return a different type depending on the number types in the data. The following example shows that `mean()` can return different types while for the same lists, `fmean()` returns `3.0`, a float for all of them.

```py
statistics.mean([2, Fraction(4,1)])   # Fraction(3, 1) <--- fractions.Fraction
statistics.mean([2, 4.0])             # 3.0            <--- float
statistics.mean([2, 4])               # 3              <--- int
```

---

Also, unlike `sum(data)/len(data)`, `fmean()` (and `mean()`) works not just on lists but on general iterables such as generators as well. This is useful, if your data is massive and/or you need to perform off-the-cuff filtering before computing the mean.

For example, if a list has NaN values averaging returns NaN. If you want to average the list while ignoring NaN values, you can filter out the NaN values and pass a generator to `fmean`:

```py
data = [1, 2, float('nan')]
statistics.fmean(x for x in data if x==x)     # 1.5
```

Note that numpy has a function (`numpy.nanmean()`) that does the same job.

```py
import numpy as np
np.nanmean(data)                              # 1.5
```