# Im having issues dividing in this python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
howManyNames = (float(input("Enter how many student names do you want to enter? ")))
studentNames = []
ages = []
averageAge = 0
counter = 0

while (counter < int(howManyNames)):
    studentNames.append(input("Enter student names. "))
    ages.append(float(input("Enter that persons age. ")))
    counter += 1

averageAge = (float(ages)) / (float(howManyNames))
print (averageAge)
```

I keep getting that TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

I know off but I can't seem to find my mistake, I know you can't divide an array with and float.... thanks everyone!

Comment: `ages` is a `list` object, not a string or a number. That's your error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the average of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
averageAge = (float(ages)) / (float(howManyNames))
```

to:

```
averageAge = sum(ages) / float(howManyNames)
```

(Note: I just removed the redundant parenthesis for aesthetic reasons.)

**Explanation**:

If you open a repl and type

```
In [2]: help(float)
```

you will get `float`'s documentation which says:

```
Help on class float in module __builtin__:

class float(object)
 |  float(x) -> floating point number
 |  
 |  Convert a string or number to a floating point number, if possible.
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
...
```

In other words, you can do:

```
In [3]: float(3)
Out[3]: 3.0

In [4]: float("3")
Out[4]: 3.0
```

but you cannot do:

```
In [5]: float([])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-79b9f7854b4b> in <module>()
----> 1 float([])

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

because `[]` is a `list` and not a string or a number which is what will be acceptable to `float` according to its documentation. It also wouldn't make sense for `float` to accept a list because its purpose is to convert a string or number to a floating point value.

In your question you define:

```
ages = []
```

setting `ages` to `[]` (of type `list`.)

Of course to find the average, you need to take the sum of the values and divide by how many values that are there. Of course, `python` happens to have a built in `sum` function which will sum a list for you:

```
In [6]: sum([])
Out[6]: 0

In [7]: sum([1,2,3]) # 1 + 2 + 3
Out[7]: 6
```

Which you need only divide by the number of values to convert the average.

Comment: thanks man! How did you know right away? I am an amateur in python so if you can please elaborate on your answer it'll help me out a lot but, your code did work! Im assuming the sum() function added up all inputs then divided by my howManTimes variable. Right?

Comment: Exactly, I added more to my answer.