# I am trying to make a program that calculates the average, maximum, and minimum? Python

Tags: python

I have figured out how to make it find the maximum and minimum but I cannot figure out the average. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
minimum=None
maximum=None

while True:
    inp= raw_input("Enter a number:")
    if inp == 'done':
        #you must type done to stop taking your list
        break

    try:
        num=float(inp)
    except:
        print 'Invalid input'
        continue

    if minimum is None or num<minimum:
        minimum = num

    if maximum is None or num>maximum:
        maximum = num

print "Maximum:", maximum
print "Minimum:", minimum
```

Comment: Do you know how to determine the average?

Comment: I don't know besides it is sum of numbers divided by total amount of numbers

Comment: So then what pieces of information do you need to add to the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you keep track of the amount of numbers entered and also the sum of all the numbers entered then you can calculate the average. e.g.:

```py
n = 0  # count of numbers entered
s = 0.0  # sum of all numbers entered

while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number:")

    try:
        num = float(inp)
    except:
        print 'Invalid input'
        continue

    n += 1
    s += num

    print "Average", s / n
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list) answer (I've searched about 1sec) gives me

```
l = [15, 18, 2, 36, 12, 78, 5, 6, 9]
print reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l) / len(l)
```

for arbitrary lists.

Comment: lol this answer is correct but rather complex for a novice question

Comment: @Martin: you're right - but I think this is not duplicate but just not researched well.

Comment: mmh, Im afraid it doesn't really answer the OPs continuously growing list issue anyway :(

Answer (score 0):

in order to calculate the average also called the mean you need to keep a running list of the numbers you've collected.

```
nums = []

while True:
    inp= raw_input("Enter a number:")
    if inp == 'done':
        #you must type done to stop taking your list
        break

    try:
        num=float(inp)
        nums.append(num)
    except:
        print 'Invalid input'
        continue

    if minimum is None or num<minimum:
        minimum = num

    if maximum is None or num>maximum:
        maximum = num

print "Maximum:", maximum
print "Minimum:", minimum
print "Average:", sum(nums)/len(nums)
```